# Need to handle git-submodules in git-archive

Tags: git, git-submodules

I need to pack git submodules inside of tarball which I create with `git-archive`.

I see that in 1.6.5 `git-archive` does not support git submodules.

I see several scripts to handle this case in the net, but I'm not sure which one to pick.

What is the best / most official way to do this?

Comment: Actually, I've found that git submodules are too broken for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596822/git-submodules-workflow/1597087

Answer (score 7):

You can try my script http://github.com/Kentzo/git-archive-all

**EDIT:**

For Mac OS X users available via homebrew: `brew info git-archive-all`