# Can I make a "deep copy" of a git repository with submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

It is easy to clone an entire project plus all its submodules:

`git clone --recursive git@github.com:homer/powerplant.git`

However, how do I create a clone that has all these submodules replaced by the HEADs of the individual sub-repositories themselves? Preferably in such a way that this can be repeated easy, as soon as something changes. The target should be a read-only "flat" version of the same overall code. No merging should be necessary.

If this is possible, it would solve my Launchpad problems where `bzr` can import only repositories without submodules.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to handle git-submodules in git-archive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591387/need-to-handle-git-submodules-in-git-archive)

Comment: I am not interesting in archiving. I just want a deep copy of a git repository where the submodule structure is gone and replaced by the corresponding code. I rather need ```git flatten``` if it would exist.

Comment: Yes, [How do I git clone --recursive and checkout master on all submodules in a single line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6474847) is better

Comment: No, that is also something else. The submodule structure will not disappear because you checkout and `bzr` will still not understand it. I really want a flattened out copy, not just an ordinary clone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to start with submodules' files but not as git repos, simply do the following:

- clone recursively `git clone --recursive git@github.com:homer/powerplant.git` (insane repo name btw)
- then un-register the submodule with `git config --remove-section submodule.name`

You'll end up with what you want, submodule files in the working tree but submodules not initialized as such.

You could have used the newest `git submodule deinit` command, but it also removes submodule's files from the working tree.

Comment: I've to check if Launchpad accepts this, but I think this is indeed along the lines I was imagining it!

Comment: Is the issue you have with Launchpad and git submodules reported somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it directly, since submodules are never referenced by  `HEAD`. It's a Git feature that prevents unwanted updated in dependencies, so submodules are referenced by the superproject at a fixed SHA1, which can be changed by committing (in the superproject) the new ones.

Updating submodules to their last revision after clone is simple, though: run the following commands in the superproject.

```
git submodule foreach git merge origin/master
git commit -am "updated all submodules to origin/master"
```

EDIT

Looks like you want to check out submodules after the clone, command is

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not that I do not know how to update the repository with submodules. I want a copy of that repository where the submodules have been replaced by their code. Or else `bzr` will not be able to import it.

Comment: Got it, see this question: [How do I git clone --recursive and checkout master on all submodules in a single line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6474847) (I included the correct answer in mine, not all are correct)

Comment: Yes, it is a different question. I think the only solution in my case, where I do not want to have any submodules in the target repository is by circumventing git entirely (and loosing the history): `rsync -avzul source-repos/ --exclude=.gitmodules --exclude=.git dest-repos/`. Now in the final repository, I do not have the submodules anymore. Compare https://github.com/dobots/aim with https://github.com/dobots/aim-bzr.

Comment: OK; so you want a dump of the repository, without the `.git` repo, and including the submodules, right?

Comment: I think that what you're after is https://github.com/meitar/git-archive-all.sh/wiki (from [How do I git clone --recursive and checkout master on all submodules in a single line?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6474847)

Comment: Nice find. It might indeed be enough to run git-archive recursively. However, in that case I prefer running `rsync` myself (as above), so I know what will happen exactly. It's a one-liner, so not a lot of trouble. I just thought there might have been a `git` option I missed.

Comment: Sure rsync can do the job here. Not sure about advantages of such a script, but there must be things it is more aware of.