# Cleanest way to checkout an earlier tag for read-only purposes in Git

Tags: git, tags, clone, git-checkout

I have a working tree on my local machine, and a remote repository as well. Let's say I want to quickly build an earlier version of my project at a known tag without disturbing the current state of the working version. My inclination is to checkout a separate tree, which seems to go like in this question:

[Download a specific tag with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/how-to-use-git-to-download-a-particular-tag)

With a clone from the remote repository followed by a checkout in there. But the clone does a lot of work and pulls down all the revision state. Is there any lightweight way of saying "grab me the current state of the world at this commit/tag and spray it into this directory?" (Further revision control not necessary-- it's "read only" as far as Git should be concerned.)

Maybe not-- just checking.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's all local, you can do this:

```
mkdir /path/to/test-tree
cd /path/to/repo
git read-tree <tag>
git checkout-index -a --prefix=/path/to/test-tree/  # don't forget the last slash

# read-tree copies content into the index
# to restore it:
git read-tree HEAD
```

That's assuming you don't care about the other tree having any git information at all. If you want it to, you could use the [git-new-workdir script](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=blob;f=contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir;h=993cacf324b8595e5be583ff372b25353c7af95c;hb=HEAD), which basically creates a clone, except populating the `.git` directory with symlinks back to the original repo, so that it takes no extra disk space. It's a nice approach - no extra disk space, and you can use one repo for development, one for testing, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
git checkout -b new_branch [previous_tag]
```

Comment: Not sure I want to create a "branch". After I'm done with my read-only tree, I'll usually just `rm -rf` it and forget about it. Creating a branch creates state inside Git, right?

Comment: @quixoto: Well, you can just do `git branch -D new_branch`, and the branch is gone as if it never existed.

Comment: Sounds like y'all are talking across each other. Chetan, the OP wants a separate tree, without disturbing the repo's current tree - so no checking out within there.

Comment: @Jefromi: Ah, I see. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for git-export: [Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)