# How do I get the Java API sources?

Tags: android, git, repository, android-source, git-clone

While there seems to be a way to [clone the whole repo](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html), [described here](http://android.opensourceror.org/2010/01/18/android-source/), I just need just the **Java API** files, nothing more. *(Hint: traffic limit + slow connection)*

Now, [here is the whole git repo](http://android.git.kernel.org/), but where are the plain Java API files? Or are they at a complete different location? Someone an idea? *I'm not that much a git expert.*

Comment: Link android.git.kernel.org doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following worked, with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/how-to-use-git-to-download-a-particular-tag):

```
git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/frameworks/base.git
cd base
git tag -l
git checkout android-2.2.2_r1
```

And then we get a nice directory: `core/java/android`

```
tar cjf android-java-2.2.2.tbz2 core/java/android
```

And then we get a nice bzip2-ed archive: `android-java-2.2.2.tbz2`, just 1.8MB ;)

Comment: nope, it doesn't include classes from Java (like ArrayList, etc.), it only has Android specific classes.

Answer (score 10):

I have no idea what you think "the plain Java API files" are.

The second link is not a git repo. It is a family of git repositories. Each row in that table is one git repo. The first link is for instructions on how to use Android-supplied tools to clone all of those repositories.

If you think "the plain Java API files" refer to the `java.*` and `javax.*` classes, they are from [the `libcore` repo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/).

If you think "the plain Java API files" refer to `android.*` classes, they are from [the `frameworks/base` repo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/).

Other repos may be contribute other portions of "the plain Java API files", such as Apache HttpClient.

If all you are trying to do is poke through the code, I recommend [Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch). For example, I refer to the Android source code frequently, and I don't have it downloaded.

**[Edit]**
And if all you want to do is develop android applications, you don't need any of this; just [download the SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for the hints to the locations! I want to browse the code offline (and fast) and use it in Eclipse (to display it), that's why I needed the sources offline.

Answer (score 0):

If u just need to see or download a specific JAVA API file from android.*.* then just refer this site

http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/

this is has repo of all android release.