# git clone a previous version of master build at github

Tags: github

How do I get the source from a previous version like a release version at github, when the master is updated daily? Sometimes later versions contain bugs I can't solve and I want to testrun an earlier version instead. But I'm not sure how to get to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually you can go to the download section at github and download a tagged commit. That's usually the stable version of that repository.

Comment: Yes, I found this eariler thread too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/how-to-use-git-to-download-a-particular-tag

Thank you!