# save old git repository versions

Tags: git, file, repository, commit, versions

For the project I'm working on, I need to save all the files of a specific version of a git repository. I've looked through a fair amount of information regarding git checkout but I can't figure out what that does to the files in the directory I have, let alone save the version of that specific commit. Does anyone know a way to get the files of a git repository at a specific commit? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Do a "git export" (like "svn export")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export)

```
git checkout [commit sha]
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master
```

However, I don't know, why. Usually one use a vcs exactly because it saves every state, so why don't you just tag it and check it out, when you need it?

Comment: Is there any way to get the files without sending them to a .zip? I need them unpacked and if I were to unpack them all, I'd be here forever.

Comment: Can't you unpack a whole archive? :? Must say: Sounds curious to me. However: After the `checkout` you have all files in the workspace. If you want to separate the checkout from the workspace you can use the first example in the link I provided (`git archive master | tar -x -C /somewhere/else`), or just make a local clone, checkout and remove git (`git clone /local/path/to/repo /another/path; cd /another/path; git checkout [SHA]; rm -Rf .git;`)

Answer (score 0):

I think `tag` will help. Every time you like to save all the current files, type something like `git tag -a v1.4 -m 'version 1.4'`. So once you want those files back, commit or stash changes first, then type `git checkout v1.4`, the files will rollback to the time you tagged. Check these link for further infomation: [how to tag](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html) and [how to get them back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/how-to-use-git-to-download-a-particular-tag).