# git archive quick unzip

Tags: git, archive, unzip

Is there any way to use the git archive command without sending all the files to a .zip? I need it unzipped, but it takes awhile if I just run that command. Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a "git export" (like "svn export")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export) (The first example) Just realise, that you are the one, who asked the very similar question short before :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001909/save-old-git-repository-versions

Comment: Yea, after reading through that question a bit more, it seems there is no efficient way to do that. This is more of a followup on the last question I asked. Thanks anyway, no point in answering.

Comment: @SSEMember, what's wrong with using `tar` format and piping to `tar`? `tar` does not compress anything, just archives so while there is certain overhead (copying in, copying out), it's lower than for zipping. Moreover, the manual for `git checkout-index` (also suggested in the discussion @KingCrunch pointed at) contains an example of how to do Subversion-style export, so it looks like a "blessed" way to do what you need.