# How do I export a specific commit with git-archive?

Tags: git, repository, export

I asked a similar question before, but it was answered inadequately so I thought I would ask again here but providing more information. I need to get different and older versions of a git repository and I'm having trouble with that. What I've tried is

```
git checkout master~X 

git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master 

git checkout master 


git checkout master~Y 

git archive --format zip --output /full/path/toDifferent/zipfile.zip master 

git checkout master
```

After unzipping both, they end up being exactly the same. I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

Comment: Try `git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip master~X`

Comment: Oh, I think I see what I did wrong. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: @Banthar Please post that as an answer so SSEMember has something to accept.

Comment: Linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001909/save-old-git-repository-versions.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### The Problem

In both your examples, you are exporting the tip of *master*. Take out your flags and arguments, and you have:

```
git archive master
```

In other words, you're explicitly doing this to yourself by specifying whatever is stored in **.git/refs/heads/master** as your tree-ish.

#### The Solution

You need to provide a tree-ish in accordance with [gitrevisions(7)](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) if you want to export a different commit. For example, to export commit *29435bc*, you could specify:

```
git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip 29435bc
```

Comment: Yep, I was correct in determining why I am an idiot. Thanks for confirming it and giving me something to accept though. I appreciate it :)

Comment: I am using second commend `git archive --format zip --output /full/path/to/zipfile.zip 29435bc` but it export the whole source code, could you suggest me whats is the issue My exact comment is `$ git archive --format zip --output C:/Users/anishanth/zipfile.zip 2dbbc28
`

Comment: calling git archive via remote With a sha1 (f.x. `git archive --remove=file:///var/git/repo/ --output /tmp/specific_ref.tar <specific_ref_sha1>`) will not work as git archive on remote will only give out the HEAD ref. If you need an archive of a specific ref, you need to perform a git clone and then call git archive from withing that working copy (i.e. leaving out the remote part of the command, fx: `git archive --output /tmp/specific_ref.tar <specific_ref_sha1>`)

Answer (score 3):

Resolution

This is an expected behaviour for the newest versions of Git.  Remote Git repositories do not allow clients to access arbitrary SHA1s. The requested objects should be accessed by a ref (i.e. file name).

[git-upload-archive-archiver-died-with-error](https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/git-upload-archive-archiver-died-with-error-448791164.html)

Comment: While you are correct, in the original question, the asker wasn't referencing a remote so this response isn't really relevant. The `git-archive` was executed within the repo itself. In the case of the original question, the `git-archive` command was explicitly exporting the same tree-ish (i.e: `master`) rather than the intended tree-ish (`master~X` and `master~Y`).