# Export all commits into ZIP files or directories

Tags: git, export, git-archive

How is it possible to export all commits into ZIP files (containing *all files*, not only patch/diff):

```
myproject-commit1-67d91ab.zip
myproject-commit2-9283acd.zip
myproject-commit3-c57daa6.zip
...
```

or into directories:

```
myproject-commit1-67d91ab/
myproject-commit2-9283acd/
myproject-commit3-c57daa6/
```

?

I was thinking about commands like:

```
git archive --format zip --output myproject-commit3.zip c57daa6
```

from [How do I export a specific commit with git-archive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018411/how-do-i-export-a-specific-commit-with-git-archive), but how to get **all commits**?

Notes:

- the goal is to do **an export** of all files of each commit, so that I can have access to them even if I don't have `git` on the machine
- the answer from [How can I export Git change sets from one repository to another via sneaker net (external files)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101425/how-can-i-export-git-change-sets-from-one-repository-to-another-via-sneaker-net) creates a `.bundle` file, but it seems impossible to access it without `git`, so it's not what I'm looking for
- this nearly works:

  ```
  for ((i = 0;; ++i)); do git checkout master~$i || break; tar czf ../myproject-commit$i.tgz .; done
  ```

  but it also archives all the files in the current directory which are **not** 
  `git add`ed to the repo... How to avoid this problem?

Comment: Try `git bundle`. It creates a bundle working like a read-only repository. See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle

Comment: @phd the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101425/how-can-i-export-git-change-sets-from-one-repository-to-another-via-sneaker-net creates a `.bundle` file, but it seems impossible to access it without `git`, so it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You hadn't explained what you want. You should do that from the start. Well, `git archive` seems to be the answer, and no, there is no single command.

Comment: @phd Thank you for your remark, I thought saying I wanted to export each commit into zip files `myproject-commit3-67d91ab.zip` was explicit enough, but now I edited to add more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, except by the methods you are already thinking about.

Specifically, to turn *every* commit into a zip archive (one separate archive per commit), simply iterate over every commit, turning each one into a zip archive.

Your method for iterating simply needs to walk all possible commits, rather than walking only all first-parents of the `master` branch, and you must use `git archive` on each such commit.  Hence:

```
git rev-list --all |
    while read hash; do git archive ...options... $hash
done
```

The command `git rev-list --all` tells Git to print out every reachable commit hash ID, in some order.  To change the order, use the various sorting options available to both `git rev-list` and `git log` (e.g., `--author-date-order` or `--topo-order`).

If you *don't* want every commit—if you want instead only first-parents of master—you can still do this with `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list --first-parent master | ...
```

Here, since Git is walking only first-parents starting from whichever commit `master` identifies, the hash IDs will be output in what Git considers forward order, i.e., backwards across the branch's first-parents:

```
...--o--o--o--o--o--o------o   <-- master
      \        \          /
       \        X--X--...X   <-- somebranch
        \         /
         X--X----X--X   <-- anotherbranch
```

None of the `X` commits will appear since they are not on the first-parent lineage.  (Without `--first-parent`, since all the commits on `somebranch`, and all but the last one on `anotherbranch`, are *also* on `master`, you would get all the `X` commits.)

[Basj adds the following, which appears to be bash-specific due to `$((i=i+1))`:]  Edit: this is a ready to use command to do it as described in the question:

```
git rev-list --all --reverse | while read hash; do git archive --format zip --output ../myproject-commit$((i=i+1))-$hash.zip $hash; done
```

[torek feels the need to add :-) : Note that the above enumerates commits sequentially, even if this is not an invertible mapping.]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @torek. I just appended the ready to use command at the end.

Answer (score 2):

I slightly improved solution by @torek.
This one export commits, that are "normally visible" using `git log` (all commits are exported in folder `zip`):

```sh
mkdir zip && git log --format=%h --reverse |
    while read hash;
    do git archive --format zip --output zip/$((i=i+1))-project-$hash.zip $hash;
done
```

If you want also date and time (without "project"), use this one:

```sh
mkdir zip && git log --format="%h %ad" --date=format:"%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M" --reverse |
    while read hash date;
    do git archive --format zip --output zip/$((i=i+1))-$hash-$date.zip $hash;
done
```

Or if you want to export all commits to folders (instead to zip archives) use this one:

```sh
mkdir zip && git log --format="%h %ad" --date=format:"%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M" --reverse |
    while read hash date;
    do git archive --format zip --output zip/$((i=i+1))-$hash-$date.zip $hash;
done && find zip -name '*.zip' -exec sh -c 'unzip "$1" -d "${1%.*}"' _ {} \; && rm zip/*.zip
```

Anyway, if you want to also keep file mode (`chmod`), use this one. It uses tar archives instead zip archives:

```sh
mkdir tar && git log --format="%h %ad" --date=format:"%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M" --reverse |
    while read hash date;
    do git archive --format tar --output tar/$((i=i+1))-$hash-$date.tar $hash;
done && find tar -name '*.tar' -exec sh -c 'mkdir ${1%.*} && tar -xvf "$1" -C "${1%.*}"' _ {} \; && rm tar/*.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the your project with specific commit in zip file using

```
https://host_url/{user_name}/{project_name}/archive/{commit_id}.zip
```

**EDIT**

You can do this using command line.

```
git archive -o commit_id.tar --remote=<repo_url> <commit_id>
```

Comment: I don't use github or anything like this in this specific case. I only have a single local repo, I don't hink a web solution will work here.

Comment: Thank you @Shravan40, but you can see I already mentioned this in the question itself, the question is more: how to get an archive of *all commits*?