# How do I git extract all files in a sha to `/tmp`?

Tags: git

When searching for ways to export a specific commit (specified by its `sha`) to a directory, I get very many pointers, each with very many answers.

Possibly, that's because such questions
[are](https://stackoverflow.com/q/160608/700648)
[under](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4479960/700648)
[specified](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11018411/700648),
making multiple answers possible.

Here is what I do *not* want to do:

- I don't want to clone my multi-gigabyte repo and then checkout. I'd like to checkout to a directory from the present repo.
- The `sha` I'd like to extract is marked by neither a `tag` nor a `branch`. In fact, the `sha` I want is still hazy. Several are candidates.

Indeed simply running `git show a1b2c3c:path/to/file/myfile.c` (which extracts a specific file from a specific commit) already does what I want, except that:

- I'd like to extract a full tree (from root), not just one file.
- `git show` sends files to the terminal. I'd like to save to `/tmp`.

My question then is: How do I extract all files in a `sha` to `/tmp`?

To provide motivation, let me mention a few use cases for this questions. These are my problem; they're not the question!

- I gave an improvised demo in the (perhaps distant) past and I'd like to determine the point the project was at.
- I had omitted to add a given file to the repo, and it sometimes takes quite a while to notice that a file was not added. I'd like to track when the file went missing.

Comment: The very first question you linked to shows how to use `git archive` to do that, what's wrong with that? How does that fail to meet your requirements?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Is `git archive sha` an option, and not just `git archive | <pipe>` and `git archive master`? Let me confirm whether it's harmless to experiment, and then experiment on my side.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the hint. It's all simple enough, of course, but since I keep looking in my "git cheatsheet" for exactly this Q&A, I've written (at least for my own reference, if not everyone's) the answer rather than delete the question. I couldn't find a formal confirmation that `git archive` does indeed leave the repo immutable, but from experiments in a fresh/isolated repo, nothing in the `.git` directory is modified, so the answer seems to be yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) suggested, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/163769/704972) almost solves the problem.

To add another use case, you may be scratching your head asking yourself:  *I was testing for specifically this case; how did this test pass at that commit!?*.

In such scenarios, it's handy to run:

```
mkdir /tmp/new_dir
git archive a1b2c3 | tar -x -C /tmp/new_dir
```

and run the test in complete isolation.

A few points to note in contrast with the almost-does-it answer:

- If you're not interested in a bzip/gzip/zip archive, but (despite the `archive` in `git archive`) rather want a straight-forward directory copy in `/tmp`, you need to create the root for extraction first.
- In case you were wondering what exactly [`<tree-ish>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) means, you can indeed specify a `sha` to `git archive`. In other words, a `sha` is <[tree-ish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4044368/704972)>.
- `tar` is usually fussy about the trailing `/`, producing different outcomes depending on whether it's present. Luckily, in this case it makes no difference whether a trailing slash is present.

For [completeness](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html), the `-x` makes `tar` extract, not archive, and the `-C` is the prefix necessary to specify a directory.