# New Git repo/branches from existing 3 folder structure (theory)

Tags: git

I am trying to get validation on how to go about setting up a git repo from our existing 3 folder structure (dev,beta,prod). I understand the technical/what commands to type part. But how do I go about creating the 3 branches from the 3 folders. Unfortunately these aren't new project we can start fresh with git on, there are lots of files already in play. And the dev folder varies a good bit from the beta/prod folders.

**Our idea**

1. Create the repo in the prod folder, making it the 'master' branch.
2. Then create a branch 'release', this would match master for now (we have no beta testing happening now, so disregarding/deleting the beta folder).
3. Next create a 'dev' branch.
4. Delete the files from the folder/dev branch?...
5. Copy files from the dev folder in?...
6. Track, stage, commit...?

***Steps 4-6** are the concerning part, I don't know if deleting all the files then copying in from the dev folder would be missing anything*

In theory this would give us the three branches we could pull/clone from to our local machines. Merging into release and prod from dev would have to be interactive/cherry-picked for a bit, which I think we can manage.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, even if it's a yelling and screaming of 'no wait, not that way!'

Comment: What VC is it in now?  Is there no migration path from it to git that would let you import the history from it?

Comment: No VC currently, we kept file changes in excel sheets per project. When we needed to push a new feature/version we moved the listed files to beta, tested, moved to prod. Keeping file versions in prod as 'filename.ext_BAC_date'. So keeping history is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a central repository

Start by creating a repository that will hold your branches.  For this example I'm just going to use the filesystem but of course in practice this would probably be hosted on a remote server:

```
$ git init --bare project.git
```

### Add the prod folder

Change to your `prod` directory and initialize a git repository there:

```
$ cd prod
$ git init
```

Create a branch named "prod":

```
$ git checkout -b prod
```

Add all your files:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'added prod files'
```

And the remote:

```
$ git remote add origin /path/to/project.git
```

And push:

```
$ git push origin prod
```

### Add the dev folder

Change to your dev folder and initialize a git repository there:

```
$ cd dev
$ git init
```

Add the remote repository:

```
$ git remote add origin /path/to/project.git
```

Create a new `dev` branch:

```
$ git checkout -b dev
```

Add all your files:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'added dev files'
```

And push:

```
$ git push origin dev
```

### Add the beta folder

Repeat the same process for your beta folder:

```
$ cd beta
$ git init
$ git remote add origin /path/to/project.git
$ git checkout -b beta
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'added beta files'
$ git push origin beta
```

### Clone your main repository

Create a working copy from your bare repository:

```
$ git clone -b prod /path/to/project.git
$ cd project
```

The `-b prod` here causes git to checkout the `prod` branch.
Look at the available branches:

```
$ git branch -a
* prod
  remotes/origin/beta
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/prod
```

And now you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the alternative that the folders you describe map better onto separate repositories rather than branches in a single repository, especially if the `dev` folder is significantly different, as you state, to the other ones.

You can create a repo for each of the branches, add them as remotes all around in every other repo, and the merge into release and prod from the dev repo (say a remote `dev/master` branch) can be a cherry-pick still. Subsequently in the future you can take this further and treat all the repos as sub-modules in an uber repo.

---

For your question, in the one repo that includes everything, you seem to be concerned with importing files in a folder into a branch. You can proceed as follows:

1. Create the branch

   `master$ git co -b devb`
2. Copy the folder over

   `devb$ cp -r /path/to/external/dev dev`
3. Add the folder and the files recursively to git

   `devb$ git add dev`
4. Commit the result

   `devb$ git commit -m "initial dev commit"`

Comment: What would be some of the benefits of keeping separate repos for dev and prod instead of branching. I am seeing it as a six in one basket/half dozen in the other basket. We'll still have to cherry-pick out merges.

Comment: @undeadDog See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873527/benefits-of-using-git-branches-vs-multiple-repositories