# How to clone a specific Git tag

Tags: git, git-clone, git-tag

From [git-clone(1) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

> `--branch` can also take tags and detaches the HEAD at that commit in the resulting repository.

I tried

```
git clone --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>
```

But it does not work. It returns:

```
warning: Remote branch 2.13.0 not found in upstream origin, using HEAD instead
```

How to use this parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a specific tag with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git)

Comment: You're right, but little difference. When I ask this question, in my situation, I needed to do this in one line and must use `clone`, and I was stuck at 'why --branch doesn't work'. The best answer of that url used `clone`->`checkout`, which cannot resolve my question. :)

Comment: Not sure if the problem persists after five months, but most likely, the tag is not *2.13.0* but *v2.13.0*. Been there, done that.

Comment: There's some good advice in the answers for the similar question linked by @VictorSergienko: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git

Answer (score 909, accepted):

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>
```

`--depth 1` is optional but if you only need the state at that one revision, you probably want to skip downloading all the history up to that revision.

Comment: Note if the ref is ambiguous and you have a branch and a tag named the same thing, this will prefer the branch.

Comment: without the optional --depth 1 this is exactly the same as OPs or do i miss something?

Comment: @463035818 Seems the same, might be OP did not really have any 2.13.0 tag on remote.

Comment: But tags are not branches. How do you get a specific *tag*?

Comment: @Melab, from a man page of git-clone, "--branch can also take tags and detaches the HEAD at that commit in the resulting repository"

Answer (score 136):

Use `--single-branch` option to **only clone history leading to tip of the tag**. This saves a lot of unnecessary code from being cloned.

```
git clone <repo_url> --branch <tag_name> --single-branch
```

Comment: Is `--single-branch` equivalent to `--depth 1`?

Comment: No, its not equivalent. --single-branch clones the history for a whole branch. With --depth 1 no history at all is cloned.

Comment: Also `--single-branch` is implied when `--depth` is used. From the manual `When creating a shallow clone with the --depth option, this is the default`

Answer (score 37):

```
git clone -b 13.1rc1-Gotham  --depth 1  https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc.git
Cloning into 'xbmc'...
remote: Counting objects: 17977, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13473/13473), done.
Receiving objects:  36% (6554/17977), 19.21 MiB | 469 KiB/s
```

Will be faster than :

```
git clone https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc.git
Cloning into 'xbmc'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 281705, done.
remote: Counting objects: 533, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (177/177), done.
Receiving objects:  14% (40643/282238), 55.46 MiB | 578 KiB/s
```

Or

```
git clone -b 13.1rc1-Gotham  https://github.com/xbmc/xbmc.git
Cloning into 'xbmc'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 281705, done.
remote: Counting objects: 533, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (177/177), done.
Receiving objects:  12% (34441/282238), 20.25 MiB | 461 KiB/s
```

Comment: `--depth 1` is a gem, so many people download the whole git history just to use the `HEAD`.

Comment: `--depth 1` should be made default; if someone tries to chechout a previous commit, they should be prompted to download the rest.

Answer (score 20):

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>
```

**Example**

> git clone --depth 1 --branch 0.37.2
> https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset.git

```
<tag_name> : 0.37.2

<repo_url> : https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset.git
```

Comment: The command is character for character exactly the same as the selected answer.

Comment: yea but check the example , it's for better uderstading

Answer (score 8):

Use the command

```
git clone --help
```

to see whether your git supports the command

```
git clone --branch tag_name
```

If not, just do the following:

```
git clone repo_url 
cd repo
git checkout tag_name
```

Comment: this is working
git clone repo_url 
cd repo
git checkout tag_name

Answer (score 1):

Cloning a specific tag, might return **'detached HEAD' state**.

As a workaround, try to clone the repo first, and then checkout a specific tag. For example:

```
repo_url=https://github.com/owner/project.git
repo_dir=$(basename $repo_url .git)
repo_tag=0.5

git clone --single-branch $repo_url # using --depth 1 can show no tags
git --work-tree=$repo_dir --git-dir=$repo_dir/.git checkout tags/$repo_tag
```

Note: Since Git [1.8.5](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git/1.8.5#git--Cltpathgt), you can use `-C <path>`, instead of `--work-tree` and  `--git-dir`.

Comment: Cloning a specific tag *will* detach HEAD. That's the point.

Answer (score -3):

I recommend

```
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:etlegacy/etlegacy.git --tags 2.80.2 --single-branch
```

Comment: Why does this work? I cannot find any documentation on this --tags option. Are you sure that's not just ignored?

Comment: Well just try the command and check the results, anyway, on Linux, use auto completion show --tag option

Comment: I tried. It doesn't work.

Comment: strange, it worked for me last week