# Git tags missing after clone

Tags: git

I have a remote that contains all tags that I need. Let's suppose tag: `A`, `B` and `C`. After clone I have only tags: `A` and `C`... Tag `B` is somehow missing...

I tried after clone `git fetch --tags`, `git pull --tags`, etc... no way!
I tried to check in my local machine doing:

```
git ls-remote my_repository_name
```

But does not shows the tag `B`! But the tag is present in the server..

I tried to push the tag `B` again to the server using another baseline and I got "failed to lock" message instead "all is updated"...

Comment: Is tag B a lightweight tag?  They are more for private use and don't have an object in the object-database to represent them.  That means, I think, they wouldn't clone without extra work.  That is, tag B may not ever have been pushed to the repo from which you are cloning.

Comment: How do you know that tag B is "missing"? Does it not show up in `git tag`? Also, is your repository public somewhere, like on GitHub or Bitbucket? If you want us to help you, you need to calm down and give us more information to work with. What is the command that you used to try to push tag `B` to your remote again?

Comment: @Wolf I tested the lightweight tags, they do get pushed and cloned, just like annotated tags.

Comment: yes I used git tag and I tried the git ls-remote as well... I know the tags exists because they are in the server but after clone they do not show up in the local repository

Comment: btw.. I tried git version 1.7.5 and now I am using 1.9.1 but no lucky!

Comment: and the odd think is... this tags missing... If I use a baseline I have those and try to push this tags I have "failed to lock"... other tags "all is updated".

Comment: @user1657666 what do you mean by a "baseline"? What is a "baseline"? What command are you using to push? Is your working copy clean? What is its `git status`? Is your remote repo hosted on GitHub?

Comment: I have the same issue, I created a repo did a bunch of commits tagging each one pushed everything to my central repo and everything seemed fine. I then created a new working folder using git clone and everything was there except my tags. For some reason the tag from my very first commit shows up but no others do.  Very strange.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. I "fixed" it by deleting my local repository and cloning again using `git clone --branch <tag_name> <repo_url>` (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699307/720773). Hopefully there is a proper fix for this other than blowing away your local repo, but I hope this workaround helps someone.

Comment: Did you try "git push --tags"?

Comment: This is an old question, stable version of git is now 1.26 ; does anyone experience the same issue today ?

Comment: @LeGEC I'm using git 2.17.1 and experience the same issue. However, the issue was solved after using @Clarus's recommendation `git push --tags`

Comment: How did you verify that the tag is "present in the server"?