# How to creating Github release that includes submodule?

Tags: github

I have a [repo on Github](http://github.com/maasha/biopieces) where I have included the Wiki as a submodule as described [here](http://brendancleary.com/2013/03/08/including-a-github-wiki-in-a-repository-as-a-submodule/).

Unfortunately, if I create a release, download, and unpack the tarball, the wiki directory is empty. Solutions?

Answer (score 1):

The [source code prepared by GitHub for a release](https://github.com/maasha/biopieces/releases/tag/v2.0) always include the repo source itself, not its submodules (as seen, for instance, [in this issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/9068)).

You could attached to that release an additional artifact, which would be the source archive of the submodule.

Only a `git clone --recursive` of your repo would include the submodule sources as well.
If you can use git commands, you'll get the submodules content as well.

Comment: So I have to manually create a tarball including the wiki and upload that as a binary to the release?

Comment: @maasha if you want to associate it to a release, yes. But cloning your main repo with the --recursive option would be easier. And you can clone at a specific tag: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21699307/6309

Comment: Right, but it is a shame there is no apparent way to have the wiki included in a tagged release.

Comment: @maasha I agree: that is a good sugestion to make to GitHub support.