# How to tag and clone till a tag in git branch?

Tags: git, tags

I have cloned a branch. Committed and Pushed changes to master/origin. 
I have to tag the branch for my committed changes. 
Can somebody tell me how to tag till my committed changes?
Also I want to know how to clone the branch till the till my tagged changes?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "clone till branch"? If you clone the repository and then checkout the branch, is this sufficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to git clone a specific tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280726/how-to-git-clone-a-specific-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You may use : `git clone --branch <tag> <repository_url>`