# github -- how to clone specific directory (not just release)?

Tags: git, github

Newbie at git, but I've been trying to figure this out for an hour. How do I clone a specific release from github?

I want these files:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/3.1.1
but that URL does not work with clone, so I can't figure out how to get them.

I *can* clone this parent URL:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info.git
but that does not seem to have the files I want.

So how can I get that specific 3.1.1 release?

UPDATE: Issue solved. My question assumed that git allows you to clone a specific directory in the repo (and not have to also clone all the other directories you don't care about). I now realize git just doesn't support that; you apparently have to clone the entire repo and then just cd into the directory you want.

Comment: When you say want, what do you mean? For download or editing?

Comment: I mean downloading to my local copy.

Answer (score 1):

Release v3.1.1 is essentially a tag.
You can clone using that tag:

```
git clone --branch v3.1.1 https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info.git
```

Or

```
git clone --branch v3.0.5 https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info.git
```

To clone "Release 3.0.5"

See [How to git clone a specific tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280726/how-to-git-clone-a-specific-tag)

Comment: Thanks, but no, that does not give the same files as  shown on https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/3.1.1  That clone command is cloning a bunch of other files. How can I get those files exactly?

Comment: @user2543623 After cloning you checkout gh-pages branch at the commit that you want. How? Please search

Comment: @AseemBansal -- Thanks, but no, I already tried that and that isn't the right answer either. "git checkout gh-pages" still gives a different set of files than is shown on  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/tree/gh-pages/release/3.1.1    Is there any way to get exactly those files?

Comment: @user2543623 What's the difference? The release is a folder inside it and you have to manually go there. What is the current commit hash that is checked out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949314/how-to-retrieve-the-hash-for-the-current-commit-in-git Is it same as the one on github for the content that you want?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it -- git simply doesn't support fetching only that one directory I want; it will always fetch every other directory under the root too, even though I don't need those. That's what I was not understanding. I though I could just clone that github sub-directory URL directly. But OK, I get it now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone anything you want with GIT.
Branches tags, commit and so on.

You simply have to pass the right parameter to the `clone` command.

#### Gow to clone specific branch? (-b flag)

```
# use the -b flag to clone a specifc branch 
git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>
```

---

#### `--single-branch` flag

> #### --[no-]single-branch
>
> Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the `--branch` option or the primary branch remote’s `HEAD` points at.
>
> Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning.
>
> If the `HEAD` at the remote did not point at any branch when `--single-branch` clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is created.

---

#### `git checkout tags/<tag name>`

Clone the repo and then checkout the desired tag:

```
# Checkout specific tag and create branch with the desired name
git checkout tags/<tag_name> -b <tag_name>
```