# How to git clone a specific tag only without getting the whole repo?

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to get [linux kernel 2.6.22.19 source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tag/?h=v2.6.22.19) for cross compiling stuff for my router, but the repo is huge (3gb) if I do

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

and then check out that tag, the clone took forever, my bandwidth is limited.

if I run this

```
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git --branch v2.6.22.19 --single-branch
```

the filesize recived is around 150mb, is this the correct way of doing it, what does this command likne mean ? v2.6.22.19 is a tag name right? why it can bed added after --branch ?

after cloning.

```
[oglop@localhost linux-stable]$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
```

Comment: Why not download one of the release tar.xz files.

Comment: because I can not find 2.6.22.19 here?  https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to git clone a specific tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280726/how-to-git-clone-a-specific-tag)

Comment: @Shuman: Use `git checkout v2.6.22.19` to make it the current branch.

Comment: @unutbu still the same. `[oglop@localhost linux-stable-kernel]$ git checkout v2.6.22.19
HEAD is now at 37579d1... Linux 2.6.22.19
[oglop@localhost linux-stable-kernel]$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

providing `v2.6.22.19` is the tag name and `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git` is the repository url, try this:

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v2.6.22.19 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

the `--depth 1` will download only the latest commit in the branch (in this case the specified branch, default the remote's HEAD branch), this will also helps with the size issues

Comment: `--single-branch` is implied by `--depth` and is therefore unnecessary.