# download the code of a particular tag of a git repo using Node

Tags: node.js, git, github, git-clone, nodegit

I want to download the source code of a private git repo hosted on github for only a particular tag. As far as I can tell there's an option of using `git clone --depth=1`. I suppose [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280726/how-to-git-clone-a-specific-tag) is the answer on how to use tags with this.

Now I want to do it in a Node.js script. I checked the [NodeGit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit) package which uses [libgit2](https://libgit2.github.com/). The problem is libgit2 [doesn't support passing depth parameter](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit/issues/1262).

So I am stuck with the last option of using `child-process` which I don't want to do, as it looks like a workaround. Is there any other way of achieving this?