# Are git pull and push repository wide operations or branch specific?

Tags: git, git-push, git-pull, git-fetch

Trying to get a real handle on git : ) Is git pull a repository wide operation? Meaning, does it update your local branches (which are tracking remote branches) across the repository, or does it only fetch and merge for the currently checkedout branch?

Is the same true for push? What does --all do for push and pull?

Any help would rock!

Also, what does fetch do? Does it grab the info (files inside of the .git folder) for a specific branch? Or is the .git folder consistent across the whole repo? If I do fetch instead of clone, I can't really do anything after that, what do I do after fetching?

Comment: Depends on the version, on the exact command, local configuration, ... read your manuals carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR summary: "it depends".

The answer is "both and neither", really.  Or "it depends".  Or something like that!

First, there are two basic operations to consider: `fetch` and `push`.  (The `pull` operation is just a shell script built on top of `fetch`, so once you know how *that* works, we can explain `pull` properly.)

Both `fetch` and `push` have *access* to entire repositories.  But in general, they do not work by sending entire repositories over the wire (or other communications channel).  They work based on *references*.

The fetch and push operations generally take "refspecs", which are reference-pairs (remote:local and local:remote respectively) plus an optional "force" flag prefix `+`.  However, they can be given just a simple reference, and the force flag can be specified with `-f` or `--force`.

Both commands have been around for a long time and have accumulated a lot of "old stuff".  The "modern" way to work with remote repositories is through the thing called a "remote", using `git remote add` to create them (and `git clone` creates one called `origin` by default).  These turn into entries in the `.git/config` file:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://...
```

The `url =` line gives the URL for both fetch and push—though there can be an extra `pushurl =` line if needed, to make pushes go somewhere else.  (There are "old ways" to run fetch and push and supply URLs directly, and so on, but let's just ignore all of them ... remotes are much better!)  This also supplies refspecs—well, one refspec, in this case—for `git fetch`.

#### git ls-remote

With that out of the way, let's start with another command entirely, `git ls-remote`.  This works like a `fetch` but without actually fetching anything:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094    HEAD
222c4dd303570d096f0346c3cd1dff6ea2c84f83    refs/heads/branch
676699a0e0cdfd97521f3524c763222f1c30a094    refs/heads/master
d41117433d7b4431a188c0eddec878646bf399c3    refs/tags/tag-foo
```

This tells us that the remote named `origin` has three ref-names.  Two are branches and one is a tag.  (The special `HEAD` ref has the same SHA-1 as `refs/heads/master`, so git will guess that the remote is "on branch `master`" as `git status` might say.  There's a bug of sorts in the remote protocol: git should be able to say "`HEAD` is a symbolic ref, pointing to `refs/heads/master`", so that your end does not have to guess.  This would fix the case of two branches having the same SHA-1 as `HEAD`.)

#### git fetch

When you run `git fetch origin`, the fetch operation starts out with the same `ls-remote`, more or less, and thus sees all the branches and tags.  If you use `--tags` it brings over all the tags too, otherwise it does something fairly complicated<sup>1</sup> that brings over all the branches and *some* tags.  It sees all *other* references as well, but by default, it does not bring those over: for instance, the remote might have `refs/notes/commits`, which is used by `git notes`, but that one does not come over.

When you alter the refspecs given to `git fetch`, though, you change what gets brought over.  The default is the one right there in `.git/config`, `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.  This refspec says to bring over all `refs/heads/*` references—all branches—and store them locally under `refs/remotes/origin/` using the same name as the branch-name on the remote.  Using `--tags` adds one additional refspec: `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.  That's how git brings over all their tags: everything matching `refs/tags/*`, which is all the tags, goes into your local `refs/tags/` under the matching name.

(You can add more `fetch =` lines and bring more stuff over.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22120725/1256452) on "remote tags" for an example.)

Now, just bringing over the reference *name* won't do much good unless git also brings over any required underlying *objects*,<sup>2</sup> as identified by their SHA-1s.  Let's say you already have `676699a...`, but not `222c4dd...`.  (You're up to date on `master` but not on `branch`.  Maybe you don't even *have* branch `branch` yet.)  The fetch operation needs to bring over that commit for sure.  That commit probably needs various files, and previous commits, and so on.  So your `git fetch` communicates with the thing on the remote that's looking at the other git repository, and they have a little conversation, where each one tells the other what SHA-1s they have now, and which ones they still need.  If yours needs `222c4dd...`, it asks the other end "what else do I need to *use* `222c4dd...`", checks to see if it has those, adds them to its list if not, checks those in more detail once added, and so on.

Having finally agreed on what to exchange, their git sends you the objects—usually in a "thin pack" if possible (the details depend on the transport)—and your git unpacks and/or repacks them as needed, and then updates your local references for any new branches, tags, or other references brought over.  (By default, your git just stores their branches in your "remote branches"—your copy of "what they had the last time I talked with them"—but updates *your* tags.  That is, there are no "remote tags", just "remote branches".)

#### An important git fetch special case

As a special case, if you give `git fetch` any arguments beyond the name of the remote—as in:

```
git fetch origin master
```

for instance—*these* refspecs override the ones in the config file, *and* (in git versions predating 1.8.4) prevent updating "remote branches".  This generally limits what's fetched, sometimes quite a bit.  (In 1.8.4 and later, they still limit the fetch, but the remote-branch gets updated anyway, which makes more sense.)  Here, a refspec that is missing a colon—like the one above—is *not* treated as if it had the same name on both sides.  Instead, "their" branch is collected up as usual, but the SHA-1 and branch name are written into `.git/FETCH_HEAD`.

(There is a very good reason for this: if `git fetch origin master` updated your `master`, you would lose all the new commits you made!  So you want it to update only `origin/master` and/or `FETCH_HEAD`.)

#### git push

The `push` operation is really very similar to `fetch`.  It's not completely symmetric though: you don't push to a "remote branch", in general, you just push right to a "branch".  For instance, when pushing your branch `master`, your local reference is `refs/heads/master`, and their local reference is *also* `refs/heads/master`.  It's not `refs/remotes/yoursystem/master`, for sure.  So the refspecs used for push are often quite a bit simpler.

If you just run `git push` (or `git push origin`), this still needs to come up with some refspec(s), though.

There is a (sort of new) control knob in the git config file, `push.default`, that allows you to configure which references git pushes.  In current versions of git, it defaults to `matching`.  In git 2.0 it is slated to change to `simple`.  There are five total possible settings:

- `nothing`: produce an error
- `current`: push the branch you are on to the same name
- `upstream`: push the branch you are on to its upstream name
- `simple`: like upstream, but require that the upstream name match the local name
- `matching`: push all branches that have the same name

Some of these require a bit of further explanation.  The "upstream name" is the branch name on the other end.  Let's say you have a remote branch named `origin/feature`, and you made a local tracking branch for it, but called it `feature2` because you were already working on a different `feature` branch (not yet created on `origin`).  So your local `feature2` has `remote/origin` as its upstream (and your `feature` has no upstream at all).  Pushing to `upstream` will follow the mapping, and push your `feature2` to their `feature`.  Pushing with `simple` will reject the attempt.

Hence, if you `git push` with no refspec, git will look up the default configuration<sup>3</sup> and construct a refspec based on that.  For the `matching` case, it pushes every branch that you and they both have (so, if you both have `master` and `branch`, push your `master` to their `master`, and your `branch` to their `branch`), but does not do anything about branches only one of you has.

If you give some explicit refspec(s), all of this becomes moot: the push operation pushes the refspecs you give it.  Moreover, a refspec without a colon means "use the same name on both ends", so `master` is a short-hand way to write the full long version, `refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master`.

As with a fetch, your git and their git communicate to figure out what repository objects, if any, need to be sent over to accomplish the push.

#### git pull

The `git pull` operation runs the four-word form of `git fetch`.

Its first step is to figure out what remote to use.  If you name one:

```
git pull origin master
```

it takes the name you give it; otherwise it looks at which branch you're on (let's say `master`), then looks in `.git/config` to find `branch.master.remote` (probably `origin`).

Then, it figures out what branch to use.  If you name one, it uses that; otherwise, it uses `branch.master.merge`, which is the name of the branch at the other end (normally just `master` again).  It then runs `git fetch` with those arguments.

This means the fetch will bring over only the "interesting" branch, in this case `master`, and put the SHA-1 in `FETCH_HEAD`.  (If you have git 1.8.4 or newer, it will also update `origin/master`.)

Finally, `pull` runs either `merge` or `rebase`, depending again on configuration entries and whether you run it with `--rebase`.  The commit you will merge, or rebase to, is the one whose SHA-1 is now stored in `FETCH_HEAD`.

**Note that this only merges or rebases your current branch.**

---

<sup>1</sup>As noted in the manual, fetch defaults to a "tag following" trick: it looks at the SHA-1s in the tags, and sees if those are or will be in your repository.  For those that are-or-will-be, it brings over that tag.  You can turn this off with `--no-tags`.

<sup>2</sup>Objects are the things that the repository actually stores: "blobs" (files), trees (directories full of files or more directories), commits, and "annotated tags".  Each has a unique SHA-1 name.

<sup>3</sup>However, you can override this with a per-branch configuration, `branch.name.pushremote` and `remote.name.push`.  You can make a twisty mass of difficult-to-understand effects by turning a lot of configuration knobs.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is super thorough!

Answer (score 2):

`git pull` is just a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`.

`git fetch` will update all remote branches, and `git merge` will update the current branch by merging the corresponding remote branch.

The exact behavior of a plain `git push` depends on the output of `git config push.default`.
Recent git versions set this to `simple` which will only push the current branch.

For the exact meaning of the command line options use `git help push` and `git help pull`.

`git clone` is just a combination of `git init`, `git remote add`, `git fetch`, and `git checkout`.

Your `.git` folder **is** your local repository containing the whole history for all files. The files outside the `.git` folder are your "working tree". The working tree is needed for changing files, but is not needed for most other git commands like `git log`.

Comment: For anyone using git 1.8.3 or earlier, there's a noticeable difference in the way `git pull` runs `git fetch`: you don't see the updates to your remote branch.  If you just run `git fetch`, it updates all the remote branches.  This winds up showing through, and it can be confusing.  No big deal if you have 1.8.4 or newer though! :-)