# Git pre-push hook, enumerating all un-pushed commits

Tags: git, githooks

I want to run a pre-push job on all un-pushed local commits.

`git rev-list BRANCH --not --remotes=origin` works great for all cases except when the remote you're pushing to is empty. When that is the case, that command will return nothing.

Is it safe to assume that if the remote sha arg is 00000 *and* `git rev-list BRANCH --not --remotes=origin` returns empty then all commits are on to be enumerated `git rev-list BRANCH`?

Is there a better way to get the information I'm after that works in all cases?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me precisely what you intend to accomplish, but any time you run `git push`:

- your git calls up their git (on the remote) and finds out what it has;
- you tell your git—often implicitly—what branch names (and/or other references) it should look at on your side, and what branch names it should try to push to on "their" side, using "refspecs" (pairs of names with a colon between them).

That is, you may run:

```
git push origin mybranch:master
```

or:

```
git push origin branch1:branch1 branch2:branch2 branch3:newname
```

or even:

```
git push origin 'refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*'
```

You might also run:

```
git push origin refs/tags/v1.2:refs/tags/v1.2
```

or (with `--tags`) include a pair of `refs/tags/*` rather like the `refs/heads/*` line.

In other words, you may not be just pushing *a* branch (you might push several), or you might not be pushing a branch at all, but rather a tag, or you might be pushing branches *and* tags.  (For that matter, there are also "notes".  Notes live in `refs/notes/`, which is a somewhat-new name space that is usually not transferred, but note the word "usually".)

In a pre-push hook, you're supposed to read multiple lines from standard input.  There will be one line for every ref-name you're proposing to create, delete, or update on the remote.

On each line, you get (as the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) notes) the local ref-name,<sup>1</sup> the local SHA-1, the remote ref-name, and the remote SHA-1, all in that order.  You can tell whether you've asked your git to create or delete the remote ref-name by examining the two SHA-1s.  At most one of these will be 40 `0`s.  For a normal update, neither one will be all-zero.

There may be no new commits, or even no new objects at all,<sup>2</sup> involved in the supplied ref-name update.  For instance, when creating a new tag pointing to an existing commit, there is nothing else to do: you just ask the remote "please create this new tag, pointing to existing commit `1234567890123456789012345678901234567890`" or whatever.  However, if you're simply removing some commit history (with a forced push), this too has no new commits: you're just asking the remote "please change `branch` to point to this new ID".

To find out what new objects (if any) would be sent, you should not look at your own *names*, as these may be out of date.  Instead, you should do the same thing as git does: concentrate on the SHA-1 IDs.

There *is* a bit of a problem here though.  Let's say, for instance, that you are asking the remote to update ref-name `refs/heads/branch` from `1234567...` to `9abcdef...`, so that the remote SHA-1 is `1234567...` and the local SHA-1 is `9abcdef...`.  This may be—indeed, usually is—a "forward" motion:

```
... <- 1234567... <- 5555555... <- 9abcdef...   <-- refs/heads/branch
```

(where the numbers here are SHA-1 IDs of actual commit objects, and you are simply asking the remote to move its branch `branch` forward two commits).  However, it's possible that the remote already has commits `5555555...` and `9abcdef...`, just not on `branch`:

```
... <- 1234567...   <-- branch
                  \
                    5555555... <- 9abcdef...  <-- develop
```

In this case, while you're updating their `branch` by moving it forward two commits, those are two commits that were already *somewhere* in the repository (in fact, on branch `develop`).

Nonetheless, those are two commits that were not on `branch` before, and will be afterward, if the push succeeds (your `pre-push` hook can stop it, but so can the remote: it can run its own hooks and decide to reject your push).

To enumerate those two commits, simply use `git rev-list` with the raw SHA-1 values, as in this [sample hook](https://github.com/raven/git-prepush-recipes/blob/master/pre-push.sample) I found on github.

If you are asking how you can *avoid* enumerating those two commits, the answer there is that there is no 100% reliable method.  You can get fairly close by running `git fetch`<sup>3</sup> before you run `git push`.  This will allow you to find all the ref-names the remote is willing to export to you, and what their SHA-1 values are.  Any commit object find-able by their ref-names is necessarily in the remote repository.

Here, `git rev-list ... --not --remotes=origin` is indeed the mostly<sup>4</sup> right thing: after running `git fetch` to get your copy of their references, you can use the raw SHA-1 to find reachable commits, and also use all of those copies to exclude commits reachable from any remote branch.  The flaw here is not just the one in footnote four (tags), but also the fact that no matter how fast your `fetch`-then-`push` sequence is, the references you copy may be out of date by the time your `push` runs.  You can make this window very small, but not (with just git alone) eliminate it.

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a caveat here, also noted in the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push): the local SHA-1 may not have a name.  This is obviously the case when you're asking the remote to delete a reference, since you request this with `git push :ref-to-delete`: there's no *name* on the left-hand side of the refspec.  However, it's also true if you push by raw SHA-1 or a relative reference, as in [gitrevisions](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).  In general this is not that big a deal since the local ref-name, if any, has no effect on the remote: all the action is due to the two SHA-1s and the remote ref-name.

<sup>2</sup>Remember, `git push` pushes *all* needed objects, not just commits: a commit points to a tree, so if there's a new commit there is probably a new tree; trees point to more trees and to blobs, so there may be additional trees and blobs; and an annotated tag is its own object type.  All of these can be transferred during a push.

<sup>3</sup>You can use `git ls-remote` to obtain current ref-name mappings, but the problem here is that if your local repository lacks the corresponding object(s), you cannot link these up with your own repository history to find precisely which objects they have that you don't.  The only way to find out what they have is to use `git fetch` to get not just the objects to which those refs point, but also the objects themselves, so as to build the commit graph.

<sup>4</sup>This, of course, totally omits tags.

Commits on the remote may be reachable through tags.  If you bring over their tag name space, however, you (and git) generally do so by copying all those tags into *your* name space.  These tags are not labeled as to their origin, so there is no way to tell if tag `v1.2` is *your* tag, or *their* tag, or both.  If you exclude commits reachable by tags, you may exclude too many commits.

To properly distinguish the remote's tags from your own, or any other remote's, you need to (re)invent ["remote tags"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108391/1256452).

Comment: To be clear, what i'm looking for here is to produce a list of commits to be pushed to the remote from within pre-push hook. It is ok if it it's inaccurate, as long as its conservative. That is to say. Some of the commits may have made it to the remote from another source before my push completes. That is perfectly ok. Thanks for the detailed response.

Comment: That sample hook works except in the case of a new branch. It enumerates ALL commits. I don't care about the branches at all really. I'm only concerned that the remote repo does or does not the commit/files.

Comment: Yes, the sample hook is being conservative: if the remote does not have label `B` and you're asking the remote to set new label `B` to point to commit `C`, you have potentially exposed every commit reachable from id `C`.  As noted above, if you want to see what the remote could already reach from some existing branch, the `--not --remotes=origin` will do that (though it may also be overly conservative due to tags or other items in the same push).