# Using Git tags - can't pull new tags

Tags: git, bitbucket

we're 2 people trying to use git on bitbucket. the developer is using simple tags to track all commits - and the QA guys is trying to pull new code in based on tags.

so dev decided to

```
git commit -v -am "($date) $comments"
git tag -a version-1 -m "($date) $comments"
git push --tags
```

The QA guy did

```
  git clone <path> ; cd $dir
  git checkout tags/version-1
```

This does the needed the first time around - but the second time - for the update tag - it give error message.

first time for QA

- check out is successful with message

  Note: checking out 'tags/version-1'.

  ```
  You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
  changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
  state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

  If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
  do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

    git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

  HEAD is now at 0c3514c... (02-28-2016) test comments
  ```

then the dev guy did his changes and then did

```
 git commit -v -am "($date) $comments"
 git tag -a version-2 -m "($date) $comments"
 git push --tags
```

It went through - and we can see the new tag on repo - with changes.

The QA guy does his changes

```
 git checkout tags/version-2
```

Error message is

```
error: pathspec 'tags/version-2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

But

If QA does

```
  git clone <path> ; cd $dir
  git checkout tags/version-2
```

it works fine !!! how can the QA guy update the same git director with new tags that the dev guy is checking in ?

Answer (score 9):

ok - found the answer as I was browsing the other links on stack.

First make sure that the tag exists locally by doing

```
git fetch --tags
```

Then check out the tag by running

```
git checkout tags/<tag_name>
```

thanks to [Git - Checkout a remote tag when two remotes have the same tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108391/git-checkout-a-remote-tag-when-two-remotes-have-the-same-tag-name) (second answer)