# how to list the files for the next git push command

Tags: git

I am trying to push a branch to origin with

```
git push --set-upstream origin v0.8
```

This seems to take forever and eventually stops with an error

```
Counting objects: 180, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
Writing objects: 100% (180/180), 538.00 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 180 (delta 142), reused 110 (delta 87)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: eef60ca4521006cb11e4b7f181bc7a1a
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File X.sql is 1537.98 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/X/X.git
  ! [remote rejected] v0.8 -> v0.8 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/X/X.git'
```

so apparently it tries to push a file with 1.5Gb named X.sql...? I can't see this file anywhere?
So I had a look at the log with

```
git log v0.8 --not --remotes=origin
```

which gave

```
commit 046332334e1f944f64a110f92434cdc26e9fafd0
Author: X
Date:   Thu Jun 9 23:47:27 2016 +0100

search branch pushed to remote

commit 4b6d7c87a34bcd43f098d54263a032bb66baf9db  
Merge: 631d55a 539e3dc 
Author: X
Date:   Sun Jun 5 22:10:28 2016 +0100

Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/X

commit 631d55a0998e99ebc7614bf4f58b85baa4e85403  
Author: X
Date:   Sun Jun 5 22:10:15 2016 +0100

once

commit 4aa7275f4381c222fff7ba9ae22ab00df886ba3b
Author: fbeutler X
Date:   Sun Jun 5 22:09:27 2016 +0100

once
```

how can I see all files connected to the commit? Just to check with one has the large file?
From the answers below I saw that I probably committed a large file and deleted it. In this case git rebase would be the way to remove it. However, rebase does not work if there is no upstream branch? 
Here is the output for rebase

```
git rebase -i
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to rebase against.
See git-rebase(1) for details

    git rebase <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> v0.8
```

If I follow this advise I get

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/v0.8 v0.8
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/v0.8' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

my problem could be solved by deleting all current commits and just re-committing and pushing my current version... is that possible?

EDIT: Here is the output for

```
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all

*   408ef30 (master) h
|\  
| * 7d4ecd3 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) new every
| * c63f869 every bug
| * a60a14a querydate bug fixed
| * 957a6d3 problem in every
| * 602891c problem in every
| * 9e827d2 problem in every
| | * 0463323 (HEAD -> v0.8, test) branch pushed to remote
| |/  
|/|   
* |   4b6d7c8 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/X/X
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 539e3dc pagedown removed, bibtex bug resolved
* | 631d55a once
* | 4aa7275 once
|/
```

Comment: `git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 046332334e1f944f64a110f92434cdc26e9fafd0` lists the files changed between 046332334e1f944f64a110f92434cdc26e9fafd0 and its parents. If X.sql is not changed in 046332334e1f944f64a110f92434cdc26e9fafd0, we can not find it here. Maybe it's changed in one of the previous commits.

Comment: It's a bit buried in my answer, but: "add `-m -p --name-status`" to get a diff for each commit.  (The `--name-status` makes the diff show just the file name and status, rather than the actual change.)  Also, the fact that there is a merge in here is troublesome as merges cannot be rebased in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: now that we have the `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` output it's easier to see what's going on and make suggestions.

#### The easy way: [BFG repo cleaner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bfg-repo-cleaner)

There's a Java based tool that basically does all the work below for you.  I have never used it myself, but it has its own tag here on StackOverflow.

#### The slightly harder way: `git filter-branch`

Since you know the name of the file, you can use `git filter-branch` to do all of the steps below in an automated fashion.  Simply use the index filter with `git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/X.sql`, and filter all of `master`, `test`, and `v0.8` branches.  But in general, you should only use `filter-branch` once you know what you are doing, and can follow all the steps below.

#### The hard way: a lot like what `filter-branch` will do, but manually

This has gotten quite long, and quoting here is going to make it longer still, but I think it is clearer this way, so here we go. :-)

The actual graph looks like this:

```
* 408ef30 (master) h
|\  
| * 7d4ecd3 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) new every
| * c63f869 every bug
| * a60a14a querydate bug fixed
| * 957a6d3 problem in every
| * 602891c problem in every
| * 9e827d2 problem in every
| | * 0463323 (HEAD -> v0.8, test) branch pushed to remote
| |/  
|/|   
* |   4b6d7c8 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/X/X
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 539e3dc pagedown removed, bibtex bug resolved
* | 631d55a once
* | 4aa7275 once
|/
```

We can see from this that `v0.8` is a branch (not a tag: useful to know but makes no difference in terms of *pushing*, just in terms of what we do when *fixing* things).  That particular branch points to commit `0463323`.  There's an extra branch name, `test`, that also points to this same commit.

The parent of `0463323` is `4b6d7c8 Merge branch 'master' of ...`.  Because `4b6d7c8` *is* a merge, it has *two* parents.  Those two parent commits are `539e3dc pagedown removed, bibtex bug resolved` and `631d55a once`.

Commit `539e3dc` is on `origin/master` and hence is already on GitHub.  It cannot possibly have the large file in question, nor can any of its parent commits (which are also on GitHub).  Commit `631d55a`, however, is not on GitHub, nor is its parent commit `4aa7275`.  There's one row further down that is missing but we can see from the `|/` line that commit `4aa7275` and commit `539e3dc` must have their histories join up at whatever commit goes there.

We still cannot tell for sure where the big file has crept in, nor where it was subsequently removed, but we start with only four possibilities:

- `0463323 branch pushed to remote` (which, despite its name, is not actually pushed; it's failed-to-push)
- `4b6d7c8 Merge branch 'master' of ...`
- `631d55a once`
- `4aa7275 once`

(these four were also in the `git log v0.8 --not --remotes=origin` output).

The reasoning in the original answer is still valid.  The big file cannot be in the topmost commit (the one pointed-to by branch name `v0.8`), because we would see the big file there.  It cannot be in that commit's parent either, because if it were, we would see the file as being *deleted* when we look at the top-most commit, and we don't.

That leaves commits `631d55a once` and `4aa7275 once` as the remaining potential culprits.  At least one of these commits, and possibly both, has the big file that we do not want.

#### We can fix this, but...

Starting from `v0.8` and following the chain down (back through history) is what found us these four candidate commits.  However, take a look at the top of the graph, where the commit labeled `master` (`408ef30 h`) resides.  This commit is *also* a merge commit, with two parents.  One parent is `7d4ecd3 new every`, labeled `origin/master`.  The other parent is `4b6d7c8 Merge branch 'master' of ...`.

This merge commit `4b6d7c8` connects to the `pagedown removed` commit that is fine and is on `origin/master`, but also to the most recent of the two `once` commits that we suspect are bad.

What this means is that in order to clear this all up, we need to:

1. Find which of the two `once` commits is bad (it may be both of them); we no longer want these.
2. Write at least one *new* commit that we *do* want, that has as its parent, the parent of `4aa7275 once`: the commit not shown that is just off the bottom of the graph.

There are multiple ways to go about this, but here is the one I think is simplest.  I'm assuming that there is something *good* in the two `once` commits, and that you *do* want a merge after these two commits, and that you *do* want to create a branch called `v0.8` subsequent to the merge, and that you *do* want `master` to be a merge commit atop most of this new chain, including the intermediate merge commit, that merges `origin/master` back into the new chain.

If these assumptions are wrong, this *is not* what you want to do (nor are the filter-branch or BFG cleaner "easy" methods really what you want).  But this is all beyond the scope of this answer.

In any case, before we take any steps, the work tree should be clean (`git status` should show nothing to commit, and we should not have modified files that can be staged for commit).  If you have in-progress work, you will need to commit or stash it (this commit or stash can be added on to the "repair" branch later if desired).  I'll assume, though, that the work tree is clean.

#### Making a new "repaired" branch

The first step is to get a new branch, in which we'll do the right things.  This new branch should branch off from the parent commit of `4aa7275 once`, which is also the parent commit of `539e3dc pagedown removed, bibtex bug resolved`.  If we had the actual ID of that particular commit we could use it here, but we don't.  Instead, we can use the `^` or `~` suffix syntax from [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

```
git checkout -b repairwork 539e3dc~1
```

This creates a new branch named `repairwork` pointing to the parent commit that is just off the bottom of our graph.

Next, we want to take the good parts of `4aa7275`, without taking the bad parts:

```
git cherry-pick -n 4aa7275
```

The `-n` (which you can spell out as `--no-commit`) tells `git cherry-pick` to extract the changes from `4aa7275`, but not to commit them yet.  Now `git status` will show changes staged for commit.

Let's say, for simplicity, that the commit we just cherry-picked is the one that adds the large file that we don't want.  All we have to do is remove it: `git rm hugefile`, for instance.  Or, perhaps commit `631d55a once` is the commit that removes it, and you'd like to squash whatever other changes are in it into this new commit.  In that case, instead of `git rm hugefile` you can just do another `git cherry-pick -n`, this time for `631d55a`.

Let's say, for simplicity again, that while `631d55a` removes the big file, it contains some additional change that you'd like to keep separate, i.e., you *want* to still have two commits.  In this case you should `git rm` the huge file, `git commit` the result, and then `git cherry-pick 631d55a` (without `-n` / `--no-commit`: since it does not *add* the huge file it's OK to just commit now).

Let's draw what we have so far:

```
* xxxxxxx (HEAD -> repairwork) once
* xxxxxxx once
|
| * 408ef30 (master) h
| |\  
| | * 7d4ecd3 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) new every
| | * c63f869 every bug
| | * a60a14a querydate bug fixed
| | * 957a6d3 problem in every
| | * 602891c problem in every
| | * 9e827d2 problem in every
| | | * 0463323 (v0.8, test) branch pushed to remote
| | |/  
| |/|   
| * |   4b6d7c8 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/X/X
| |\ \  
| | |/  
| | * 539e3dc pagedown removed, bibtex bug resolved
| * | 631d55a once
| * | 4aa7275 once
| |/  
|//
*  xxxxxxx some commit msg
```

Note that everything we do here *adds new commits* to the repository.  **Git is much like [the Borg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek))** from Star Trek, in that every time you do anything, you simply add to its collective.  What we are doing here is adding new commits that *strongly resemble* the originals, except that the huge file is no longer included.

Now that we have the two `once` commits—or, if it makes more sense, have squashed the two `once` commits down to a single `once` commit—that are (or is) similar but omit(s) the giant file, we can redo the `Merge branch 'master' of ...` step, i.e., copy commit `4b6d7c8`.

Unfortunately, there is no way to copy a merge directly.  The easiest thing is just to re-perform the merge.  We're on some new commit on `repairwork` so we can just run `git merge 539e3dc`.  This will merge our new `once` commit(s) with `539e3dc pagedown removed, bibtex bug resolved` in the same way that we did it before, when we ran `git merge` to create `4b6d7c8`.  When the merge is done and we have the opportunity to edit the merge commit message, we can put in whatever message we want, which may be the same "Merge branch 'master' ..." thing, or we can write our own more-meaningful message, such as "re-merge without huge file".

Let's draw *part* of this result:

```
* xxxxxxx (HEAD -> repairwork) "re-merge without huge file" 
|\
* | xxxxxxx once
* | xxxxxxx once
```

#### We're now at the point where we can create a corrected `v0.8` branch.

All we have to do now is `git checkout -b v0.8-fixed` (it needs a different name, `v0.8` is already in use) and then `git cherry-pick v0.8` or `git cherry-pick 0463323`.  Either cherry-pick command does the same thing: we're just resolving the name, `v0.8`, to the target commit.  Once we've finished the cherry-pick, we are done with the old, broken `v0.8`, so we can rename it and rename our corrected one `v0.8`:

```
git checkout -b v0.8-fixed       # make new branch
git cherry-pick v0.8             # copy one commit to it
git branch -m v0.8 v0.8-broken   # rename broken branch
git branch -m v0.8               # rename our branch
```

If we `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all` now, it starts like this:

```
* xxxxxxx (HEAD -> v0.8) branch pushed to remote
* xxxxxxx (repairwork) "re-merge without huge file" 
|\
* | xxxxxxx once
* | xxxxxxx once
```

It should now be possible to push `v0.8` to the remote.  This still has four commits to transfer, but *none of these four* have the huge file.

We can also delete the old `test` branch now (`git branch -D test`) and make `test` point to the current commit (`git branch test`).

Note that the huge file *is still in our repository*:

- It's under `v0.8-broken`, which has that chain of four commits, at least one of which has the huge file.

  We can simply forcibly delete `v0.8-broken` once we're sure we are done with it, i.e., once the "fixed" `v0.8` is pushed and all looks good to everyone.
- It's also is also underneath `master`, though, as we have not yet repaired `master`: one of `master`'s parents is `4b6d7c8 Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/X/X` and that particular commit has `631d55a once` as one of its parents, and `631d55a` and/or `4aa7275` have the huge file.

We can repair `master` by this same process, namely making new "good" or "repair" branches, then copying commits and/or re-doing the merges.  Making a *new* branch will lose the current `master` upstream setting (though that's easily fixed as well).  There is a shortcut to repairing `master` though, due to the fact that there is just the one merge to re-do.  We can get onto `master`, hard-reset it to a good commit, then re-do the merge:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <some commit>
git merge <another commit>
```

When we do this we have our choice of which commit to hard-reset-to, and which one to merge.  The merge result has, as its *first* parent, the commit that we hard-reset-to.  Its *second* parent is whatever commit we name in the `git merge` command.

In your original sequence, the first parent is the other merge, and the second is `origin/master`.  This may be what you want, although it has been nicknamed a ["foxtrot merge"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35962754/1256452) and it is often the wrong way around.  (It's what you get from using `git pull`, and `git pull` is usually the wrong thing to do, for reasons described in that other question and its links.)

(Original answer below line.)

---

As I noted in a comment on your other question, `git push` works by identifying which commits you have in common with the remote you're pushing to, and which commits you have that they don't.<sup>1</sup>  In this case the remote is named `origin`.  We cannot tell which commits you and they have in common, and which ones you have that they don't, from this:

> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin v0.8
> ```

but you can.  We'll get to that in a moment.  First, here's the same background information as in the comment I made, but in more detail.

Your `git push` command needs to send the commit (or annotated tag object) to which `v0.8` resolves (I am guessing this is the `046332334e1f944f64a110f92434cdc26e9fafd0` you are showing, although you have not shown how you got this particular ID).  Your `git push` sends this commit, plus whatever other commits, trees, and blobs are needed, and then asks their Git to set a branch or tag (it's not obvious which one this is) named `v0.8` to point to that commit ID.  You and they will then be in sync, at least with respect to this `v0.8`.

Somewhere associated with this set of commits that your Git will push, there is a Git tree with a very large file (or blob) object.  Exactly which commit is something you will have to pin down and then do something about.

Here is an example of *how* such a thing comes about.  Suppose, for instance, that you start in sync with the upstream repository.  You then add, on an existing or new branch, a new commit, by doing something like this:

```
git add . && git commit -m 'add stuff'
```

In this "stuff" is that enormous file.  Whoops, well, we can just remove it and commit again, right?

```
git rm bigfile && git commit -m 'rm 1.5 GB file'
```

If we tried to push at this point, the push would fail, because they (the remote, in this case GitHub) have something set up to detect and reject large files.  We'll be pushing two commits: one that adds `bigfile` and a second one that deletes it.  This means we have to push the big file itself, which takes forever because your data rate is limited (approximately 500 MiB at approximately 72 kiB/s = about 7111 seconds = about 118.5 minutes = nearly two hours).

Apparently it's not this particular point, though, because if it were, assuming your `git diff-tree` argument is correct, we'd see the *removal* of the big file in the diff-tree output.  However, if we don't push *yet*, but instead go on to add still more commits, and *then* push, we will still have to push the enormous file: it's in one of those commits, and we have to push *all* of them: a commit is only valid if its ID matches the hash of all of its contents, and a commit's contents include the IDs of its parent commits, which include their parents, and so on, all the way back to the beginning of time.<sup>2</sup>  A repository must have all of the intermediate commits in order to have all the final commits.<sup>3</sup>

The trick, then, is to find the commit(s) that refer to the big file.  Only you can do that because only you *have* the big file.

#### How to find the commit(s)

Here is how to list the commits your Git will push.  Start by running `git fetch origin` to update your repository if needed—it's probably not needed, but it's usually worth doing anyway—and then run this command:

```
git log v0.8 --not --remotes=origin
```

(this is not quite perfect, as it ignores tags on `origin`, but at worst this will list too many commits, not too few).

The idea here is simple: your remote-tracking branches record every commit they have on every branch that they have.  (This is why we ran `git fetch`, to get this information updated.)  You have some commit(s) on `v0.8` that they do not.  We use `v0.8` to select every commit that *is* on `v0.8`, but then add `--not --remotes=origin` to *de*-select every commit that is on any `origin/*` remote-tracking branch.  (This is where the error creeps in: we should also exclude commits they have on tags they have, but we cannot easily tell which tags *they* have, at this point.  [If Git kept "remote tags"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22120725/1256452), instead of stuffing them all into a single namespace, we could fix that here.)

Whatever is left, is probably a commit we have to push, so we can `git log` those.  Add `-m -p --name-status` to get a name-and-status diff of every commit (including pesky merge commits, which `git log` normally skips diff-ing; this is the `-m` flag).

We have even more information, though, so it's very likely you don't need to do that.  Let's take a look at what your Git and GitHub's Git talked through:

> ```
> Counting objects: 180, done.
> ```

From this, we know that after your Git and their Git had their conversation to determine which commits, trees, blobs, and annotated-tag objects you had, that they didn't, that your Git would have to send, your Git had 180 such objects.

> ```
> Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
> Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
> ```

Your Git was able to compress 92 of those objects against objects that your Git knows that their Git has, or against objects your Git was sending, by virtue of the fact that if their Git has a commit, it also has every tree and blob that go with that commit, *and* every commit, tree, and blob in *all* of the history of that commit, back to the beginning of time.  (See footnote 2 again.)

> ```
> Writing objects: 100% (180/180), 538.00 MiB | 72.00 KiB/s, done.
> Total 180 (delta 142), reused 110 (delta 87)
> ```

All 180 objects made it across.  I'm not sure off-hand what the additional numbers really mean (just that they come from `git pack-objects --fix-thin`).

> ```
> remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try ...
> remote: error: Trace: eef60ca4521006cb11e4b7f181bc7a1a
> remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
> remote: error: File X.sql is 1537.98 MB; this exceeds ...
> ```

All of these messages prefixed with `remote:` come from scripts that their Git runs.  One of the things GitHub does is (obviously) to scan incoming commits for large files.  It found one such, this `X.sql` at 1.5 GB (which compressed to 1/3 of its size since your Git only had to send a mere 0.5 GB :-) ).

One of them says `trace:` and prints a Git hash value.

I cannot find any specifics on what this `trace` message is showing, but for it to be *directly useful*, it *should* be the commit ID.

You can test this for yourself:

```
git cat-file -t eef60ca4521006cb11e4b7f181bc7a1a
```

will show the type of the object in question (if it is a valid object).  If it turns out to be a blob or tree, rather than a commit, then the reason it's not documented is that it's kind of useless—not that we cannot find a commit containing a specific tree or blob, but that they had the most-useful bit of information right there, but gave us less-useful information instead.

If it *is* the commit ID, look at that particular commit (`git log -1 eef60ca4521006cb11e4b7f181bc7a1a`, for instance).  Then use something like `git rebase -i` to amend that commit, or to squash it commit together with a commit that removes the large file.  Since the large file is not in the end-point commit, you have a removal commit in there already; whether it's suitable for squashing depends on the commit, and what you want to have show up in the commit history you present to the rest of the world by pushing.

Just for completeness:

> ```
> To https://github.com/X/X.git
>   ! [remote rejected] v0.8 -> v0.8 (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/X/X.git'
> ```

This tells us that the large-file-rejection happens in a pre-receive hook, and that you were pushing via `https`.  The `v0.8` on the left is your name and the `v0.8` on the right is theirs.  Git does not distinguish between branch and tag push failures even when explicitly pushing tags:

```
$ git push origin refs/tags/derp2
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: pre receive hook
remote: found tag
To [redacted]
 ! [remote rejected] derp2 -> derp2 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to '[redacted]'
```

although successes are reported as `new tag`.  (I set up a test `pre-receive` hook that simply rejects all tags, to check this).

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, your Git gets a list of names (branches, tags, and other references) and object IDs from their Git.  These could, in general, be any type of object.  Branch names, however, can only point to commits; tag names normally point to either an annotated tag, or directly to a commit.  I have played with manually tagging blobs and trees, and this does work, but it's not normal.

<sup>2</sup>This structure, where non-leaf nodes of a tree carry hash values of their children, is called a hash tree or [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree).  In version control systems like Git and Mercurial, the commit graph is a DAG with its parent/child relationships reversed so that commits can be read-only, but the theory still applies.

<sup>3</sup>A *shallow* repository is one in which this rule is relaxed.  Shallow repositories are by definition not authoritative, since their Merkle trees cannot be verified.  Git's implementation currently only allows shallow repositories to work in the "fetch" direction (the Git doing the fetching gets correct parent IDs for each "uprooted" commit, but then stubs off the graph with a special graft entry to make it act as if it were a root commit).  The sender and receiver must both cooperate to make this work.

Comment: thanks for the answer. You are correct, the large file probably made it in an earlier commit... however, git rebase cannot be used for branches which do not have an upstream branch, right? Or how would you do this?

Comment: Rebase just copies commits.  When there is an upstream, rebase can automatically compute which commits to copy.  Whether or not there is an upstream set, you can *tell* rebase which commits to copy, by naming a commit (the `<upstream>` argument), and optionally an additional `--onto` commit (the default is again the `<upstream>`).  I'm going to run out of room here, but when you name an explicit upstream, rebase uses the equivalent of `git rev-list HEAD --not upstream` to look for commits to cherry-pick.  The `--onto` target is also that named upstream.  Hence,

Comment: ... once you know the first new commit you'll be pushing, you can `git rebase -i` onto that commit's parent, which is both the first commit *not* to push, and the first commit onto which you want to grow the replacement sequence.  (I find that this makes more sense to most people when drawn, in graphic form.)

Comment: hi torek... I appreciate your help but I am completely lost... I added above the results for rebase, but this does not seem to work... is there a way to delete all old commits and just commit/push the current version?

Comment: @carl: yes, sort of.  Before you resort to that, though ... how did you *create* your local `v0.8` branch, or is it a tag?  What command did you do, and what branch, if any, were you on at the time?  You might also post a snippet of output from `git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all`, paying particular attention to the part of the graph that has `v0.8` and how it connects to the *rest* of the graph.  Given what `log v0.8 --not --remotes=origin` showed, I'm wondering if you've run into some sort of bug on GitHub, although that seems unlikely.

Comment: I create the branch with git checkout -b v0.8 and I was in master when I did that... I included the output for your command above

Comment: That's quite an interesting history, as your `master` and `origin/master` are rather disjointed.  It does look, from this, like the `trace` output from GitHub is useless.  Let me edit the answer, but first I should get some breakfast...