# detecting a changed tag on a remote

Tags: git

I have a git repo which I am watching or changes.  One of the things I want to know is whether a tag has changed upstream.  Specifically, I think the tag resolves to `abc123` (`git rev-list -n1 tagname`) but the upstream has deleted the tag and recreated it at `def456`.

Even after I `git remote update`, my local `rev-list` shows me `abc123`.

I found `git ls-remote origin tagname`, but that shows me a hash that is not `abc123` nor `def456`.

To make matters a little more complicated, I don't actually know whether the user has given me a rev like "HEAD" or a rev like "tagname" or a rev like "abc123def456".  `rev-list` is great in that it takes all of these, but not wrt a remote.

Is there a way to say "what hash would XYZ resolve to in this specific remote" without knowing what XYZ means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know, there are two kinds of tags, *annotated tag*(created via `-a, -s or -u`) and *lightweight tag*. The annotated tag, like a commit, a blob or a tree, is an git object that has its own hash sha1. The lightweight tag is simply a name for an object. A tag usually points to a commit object, but it can also point to a tag object, a blob object or a tree object.

Supposing `tagA` is an annotated tag pointing to current tip of `master` and `tagB` is a lightweight tag pointing to the same commit, `git rev-list -n1 <tagA>` or `git rev-list -n1 <tagB>` can show the sha1 of that commit. `git ls-remote origin <tagA>` shows `tagA`'s own sha1 instead of that commit's, but `git ls-remote origin <tagB>` shows the sha1 of that commit.

If you want to find out what the tag points to, you could run `git fetch origin <tagname>` first, which passes it to `FETCH_HEAD`. `git rev-list -n1 FETCH_HEAD` can list the commit sha1 it points to in the remote, if it does point to a commit.

Answer (score 0):

You have essentially just two options, assuming only standard Git tools (if you have non-Git tools, especially ones you can program, you can of course do whatever you like).  These two options are:

1. Use `git fetch` as already described in [ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39061925/1256452).
2. Sticking with `git ls-remote`, note that `git ls-remote` *resolves* tags<sup>1</sup> for you:

   ```
   $ git ls-remote origin
   [snip]
   aaa74e8c5b085572ee6bf3381167c1d428c8d685    refs/heads/pu
   8bb94d66bf85d73f8866611161fb6022d68fdf13    refs/heads/todo
   d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0
   3d654be48f65545c4d3e35f5d3bbed5489820930    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0^{}
   33682a5e98adfd8ba4ce0e21363c443bd273eb77    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1
   729ffa50f75a025935623bfc58d0932c65f7de2f    refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.1^{}
   [snip]
   ```

If you save all of this output, you can scan through it for branch and tag names.

Branch names are simply references of the form `refs/heads/*`: in this case the remote Git has branches `pu` and `todo`, for instance.  Since branch names always point to commit IDs, the hashes to the left of these names are commit hashes.

Tag names are simply references of the form `refs/tags/*`: in this case, the tag list begins with numerous `gitgui-*` tags.  Each of these is an annotated tag, so `git ls-remote` shows not only the tag *object* ID such as `d5aef6e4d58cfe1549adef5b436f3ace984e8c86`, but also that tag object's *target*, `3d654be48f65545c4d3e35f5d3bbed5489820930`.  This is the second line of output, showing `refs/tags/gitgui-0.10.0^{}`, which is [`gitrevisions` syntax](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

> A suffix ^ followed by an empty brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until a non-tag object is found.

Note that if you do wish to "re-fetch" tags via `git fetch`, you can tell your Git to force-update your tags, or force-update the other Git's tags into a private namespace of your own ("remote tags", if you will: see [Git - Checkout a remote tag when two remotes have the same tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108391/1256452)).  To make Git force-update your current tags, add `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` to your fetch refspecs (either on the command line, or in a `fetch =` configuration entry).  Overwriting your current tags does, of course, have the obvious drawback that you no longer have the old tags.