# git with many remotes: get the hash that corresponds to a tag of a remote other than origin

Tags: git

I have a [git](/questions/tagged/git) project `project1` with two remotes (to simplify):

```
git remote -v

lib1  gituser@gitlab.com:group1/lib1 (fetch)
lib1  gituser@gitlab.com:group1/lib1 (push)
origin  gituser@gitlab.com:main/project1 (fetch)
origin  gituser@gitlab.com:main/project1 (push)
```

Please note that **lib1** is another [git](/questions/tagged/git) project.

I need to get the [git](/questions/tagged/git) hash of the tag **5.344.45** that belongs to **lib1**.

When I run `git show 5.344.45` I get the commit of the main project **project1**, clearly because both of the two projects have a tag with that name.

I tried `git rev-list --remotes=lib1 --tags=5.344.45`, but I get the [git](/questions/tagged/git) hash of the commit that the branch refs/remotes/lib1/master refers to.

So the question is, how to tell [git](/questions/tagged/git) this: please give me the commit of the tag **5.344.45** belonging to the remote **lib1** ?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108391/git-checkout-a-remote-tag-when-two-remotes-have-the-same-tag-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `git ls-remote lib1 refs/tags/5.344.45` (online operation).

You can also `git fetch lib1 refs/tags/5.344.45`, which will both set the symbolic reference `FETCH_HEAD` to be the commit that tag points to, and ensure that you actually have that commit and everything that it refers to downloaded. You can then do what you want with `FETCH_HEAD`.

Comment: This fixes it! thx. However, the hash I'm getting is different from the hashes that I see on the gitlab network page.