# how to reset a git working tree to an updated commitish

Tags: bash, git

I need to extend a given tool with a Bash script that is supposed to work with Linux and MacOS. The script gets 2 parameters:

1. A repository location (file system, ssh, http(s), ...)
2. A [commitish](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html#_specifying_revisions), e.g. branch, tag, commit hash

**I have no influence on the parameters**

The result of the script's run should be that

- the repository is cloned to a fixed destination (always the same for one repository)
- the repositorie's working tree should correspond to the *latest* state of the comittish (e.g. if it was a branch the tip of that branch)

If the repository does not (yet) exist locally, the procedure is as simple as

```
git clone $REPO_SOURCE $REPO_DIR
cd $REPO_DIR
git checkout $REPO_REF
```

My question: Consider a repository is already cloned to `/repos/foo`. After an obvios `git fetch`, how to I update that repository to the provided `$REPO_REF`?

- If `$REPO_REF` was a branch, a  `git checkout $REPO_REF && git pull` should work
- If it was a commit hash, there was no update needed (just `git checkout $REPO_REF`?)
- If it was a tag, then the tag might have been moved on the origin, how to handle this?
- How to handle other edge cases?

Is there a simple `reset-repository-to-this-commitsh` way, so the repository behaves just as if it was freshly cloned?

Side nodes:

- The same repository might be used with different *commitish*'s, but only sequentially: It is guaranteed that the script isn't invoked more than once at the same time
- All external changes to the repository might be always discarded without notification
- While deleting and cloning the repository would work, it is impractical due to their sizes and it being an *ugly* solution
- No (git) changes are needed, so checking out a detached head is okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a "standard" git clone you could to this:

```
# cleanup old cruft
git reset --hard HEAD
git clean -fdx

# detach from current branch (if on any)
git checkout --detach
# delete all local branches
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:strip=2)" refs/heads |xargs -r git branch -D
# fetch and update all remote refs and tags
git fetch --force --all --tags --prune --prune-tags
# checkout
git checkout "$COMMITISH"
```

That way you can rely on `git checkout` to do its job as usual and you don't need to replicate any of its heuristics, shortcuts etc.

Answer (score 2):

The only totally-foolproof yet convenient way is to have the *other* Git (the one you might be cloning, but might not) resolve the name for you.  Then you have a hash ID and a hash ID is universal.

If the name is a branch or tag name, you can use `git ls-remote` to achieve that step.  If it might be some other formulation (e.g., `master~13`) you're out of luck here.  So, if you need to resolve the name locally:

- If tag discipline is obeyed, no tag will ever move.  This means that if you have an existing clone that has the tag, it has the right tag, and you're OK here, and if you have an existing clone that doesn't have the tag, you can add the tag and resolve it.
- If tag discipline is not obeyed, you'd have to delete and re-create the tags (yuck), or else re-invent *remote tags:* copy their `refs/tags/*` names to your `refs/rtags/<remote>/*` name-space.  See [Git - Checkout a remote tag when two remotes have the same tag name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108391/1256452).
- If you have a branch name or something relative to a branch name, turn the branch name into your own remote-tracking name (e.g., replace `master~13` with `refs/remotes/origin/master~13`) and resolve it.

In any case, you now have a hash ID and can use detached HEAD mode.

Comment: I do really like the `git ls-remote` approach, thanks! Do you see any chance to get it to work work with commit hashes as well (i.e. how to detect if the provided parameter is a valid git hash in origin to omit `git ls-remote` in favor of that *raw* value)?

Comment: Git assumes, at least for now, that anything that's *exactly* 40 characters long *and* all-hex-digits must be a raw hash ID. (I.e., even if you create a branch or tag name that has this form, the string is taken as a hash ID—even if it's not a valid one—at least for `git rev-parse`.) This might change with the switch to SHA-256, but might not. So at least for now you can run `git ls-remote`, collect the output, and match up the string, *unless* it's exactly `^[0-9a-f]{40}$` in (some) regex terms, in which case you just use it as is.

Comment: thanks for the update. I should have been more precisly. Right now the use case depends on shortened (i.e. prefix) hashes as well. Is there any way to validate them with `ls-remote` or another mechanism against the remote as well?

Comment: @muffel: no. Shortened hashes are problematic: is `face2face` or `deadbeef` a hash, or a branch name?

Comment: Well, I'd say it's the responsibility of the user to provide unambiguous values and consider it a hash if it's neither a tag not a branch name

Comment: [The gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) tells you how Git deals with the ambiguity here. Something that *resembles* a hash ID, but shortened, *is* a hash ID *if it matches just one object in the entire repository database of hash ID keys*. The `ls-remote` command doesn't spill out the full set of keys: it only gives you those hash IDs that are represented by reference names (or more precisely, some exposed subset of reference names, but usually all).