# How to clone latest tag in a Git repo

Tags: git

```
git ls-remote --tags git://github.com/git/git.git
```

lists the latest tags without cloning.
I need a way to be able to clone from the latest tag directly

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git

Answer (score 9):

Call this `~/bin/git-clone-latest-tag`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail
basename=${0##*/}

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    printf '%s: Clone the latest tag on remote.\n' "$basename" >&2
    printf 'Usage: %s [other args] <remote>\n' "$basename" >&2
    exit 1
fi

remote=${*: -1} # Get last argument

echo "Getting list of tags from: $remote"

tag=$(git ls-remote --tags --exit-code --refs "$remote" \
  | sed -E 's/^[[:xdigit:]]+[[:space:]]+refs\/tags\/(.+)/\1/g' \
  | sort --version-sort | tail -n1)

echo "Selected tag: $tag"

# Clone as shallowly as possible. Remote is the last argument.
git clone --branch "$tag" --depth 1 --shallow-submodules --recurse-submodules "$@"
```

Then you can do:

```
% git clone-latest-tag https://github.com/python/cpython.git
Getting list of tags from: https://github.com/python/cpython.git
Selected tag: v3.8.0b1
Cloning into 'cpython'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4346, done.
...
```

Comment: I suppose the command should be "git-clone-latest-tag" and not "git clone-latest-tag", isn't it?

Comment: @Cris70 not so, `git` internally looks for scripts called `git-*`  Using `git clone-latest-tXX` will also give you `The most similar command is
        clone-latest-tag
`

Comment: For Windows users: Open git-bash. Type `cd /bin`. Then type `start .` to open `/bin` directory in your explorer (usually `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin`). Insert the script here.

Comment: This is wrong. version sorting is not based on "natural sorting" but lexicographical order, so v0.9.1 will be considered as "more latest" than v0.10.0, etc. UPDATE: Edited the answer to include `sort -V`

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner will get you a clone of a repo of just the latest tag.

```
REPO=https://github.com/namespace/repo.git && \
git clone $REPO --single-branch --branch \
$(git ls-remote --tags $REPO | cut -d/ -f3 | sort -V | tail -n1)
```

### Explanation

1. First we set a REPO variable. We need it twice, this reduces the chance of errors.
2. Then we use the next command to:

   - Get the tags from the remote
   - `cut` away everything but the tag name from the strings
   - use `sort` with the natural version sorting flag
   - use `tail` to get the last in the sorted list
3. That then becomes the 'branch' to clone

Tried this with a few repo's. No caveats come to mind (repo's without tags will fail of course), but do let me know if this can be improved.

Add `-c advice.detachedHead=false` to not get a long warning about the detached state.

### Semantic version pinning

If you'd like to pin a semantic version, you can pipe the `cut` output through this command.

```bash
grep -E "v?[0-9]\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"
```

You can replace each `[0-9]` to pin the major, minor, or patch version. For example:

```bash
MAJOR_VERSION=2
REPO=https://github.com/namespace/repo.git && \
git clone $REPO --single-branch --branch \
$(git ls-remote --tags $REPO | grep -E "v?${MAJOR_VERSION}\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+" | cut -d/ -f3 | sort -V | tail -n1)
```

Would get the latest v2.x.x from that repository

Comment: While this might be out of your control, repos that go through a versioning change will have issues. One example is `helix-editor/helix`. The latest is 22.08, and it's in the middle of the list.

Comment: And the only workaround I have found is to just clone the repo first, then I'm able to checkout the latest tag with `--sort=taggerdate` added. It appears that all of the 'by date' sorting keys require object data, which means you can't just clone the latest tag. For my purposes, this is still close enough.

Comment: This is wrong. version sorting is not based on "natural sorting" but lexicographical order, so v0.9.1 will be considered as "more latest" than v0.10.0, etc.

Comment: Indeed! Added `sort -V` to ensure the tags are sorted naturally. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Clone repo
$ git clone <url>

# Go into repo folder
$ cd <reponame>

# Get new tags from the remote
$ git fetch --tags

# Get the latest tag name, assign it to a variable
$ latestTag=$(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)

# Checkout the latest tag
$ git checkout $latestTag
```

Found this solution [here](http://julienrenaux.fr/2013/10/04/how-to-automatically-checkout-the-latest-tag-of-a-git-repository/)