# Increase depth of shallow clone without fetching other branches

Tags: git, git-clone, git-fetch

To save disk space, I generally shallow clone:

- [The latest remote git tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29780641/5353461)
- The default branch with:

  `git clone --depth 20 --shallow-submodules --recurse-submodules`

How do I increase increase the depth of a shallow clone?

Note: I don't want to [increase to a full clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6802145/5353461), I  want to deepen only what I already have.

Answer (score 5):

Use `git fetch --deepen=<depth>`:

[`man git-fetch`](https://manned.org/git-fetch) says:

> ```
>   --deepen=<depth>
>        Similar to --depth, except it specifies the number of commits from
>        the current shallow boundary instead of from the tip of each remote
>        branch history.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid fetching other branches, just specify the remote and branch:

```
git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name> --deepen=<depth>
```

The command will fetch and add `<depth>` additional commits to the shallow clone.