# How to checkout a file in git based on a tag

Tags: git, tags

I have a  commit hash `abcx` and I have given it a tag `100`.
Now I want to checkout a file `example.pl` to that tag `100`. Is it possible in git?
I can do `git checkout abcs example.pl`, but I directly want to **checkout a file based on the tag**.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: How it would be working if you had 2 commits tagged as "100"?

Comment: the tags are unique in this case

Comment: oh yes sorry then git checkout tags/100 :) from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git

Comment: Then it would checkout the entire repo to 100 . I just want a file to checkout to 100

Comment: git checkout tags/100 example.pl

Comment: But when I do git log example.pl it shows me revisions even above 100

Comment: because you changed the state of local file, not its history

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76352/discussion-between-cerkiewny-and-newbie).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because of how [tags work in Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging), they are basically just read only branches which you can treat as any branch in Git. You can address them as `tags/<tag>`.

To checkout the entire state of the repository to the working directory with a tag, you write:

```
git checkout tags/<yourtag>
```

But as with a case of normal branches you can decrease the scope of the checkout to individual files by listing them:

```
git checkout tags/<yourtag> <file1> <file2> ...
```

The behaviour you are seeing with the log happens because of the fact that Git has two methods of pointing to the repositories. Either your local repository pointer is being changed when you checkout entire repository with:

```
git checkout <tag/hash>
```

or individual statues of the files changes when you check them out to specific state with:

```
git checkout <tag/hash> filelist
```

Even if you do checkout all your files to the previous repository state:

```
git checkout <tag/hash> *
```

your pointer of local repository won't change. The git log is using the local repository pointer to log the changes on the file so it will be aware of the "future" changes that happened before the state of the file you checked it into. So from the git perspective command:

```
git checkout <tag/hash/branch> file
```

is not affecting the repository pointer, it is only changing the state of the files to match the specific point in time, if you will run the git status you will see those files as local changes, it doesn't differ in any way from taking the copy paste from the state of the file in the repository.

Comment: Then how can I find to which tag the file belongs to ?