# Maven issue while Building for a latest fix given by WSO2

Tags: maven, wso2, governance-registry, wso2-governance-registry

`WSO2` has given a latest fix for `Governance Registry5.3.0`(Governance `REST API` Update issue). While building a code for applying a fix the below error is thrown.

Error when building code using `Maven`.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project  org.wso2.carbon.governance.api: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Users\a596500\Downloads\carbon-governance-master\components\governance\org.wso2.carbon.governance.api\src\main\java\org\wso2\carbon\governance\api\util\CheckpointTimeUtils.java:[22,30] error: package org.apache.commons.lang does not exist
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project org.wso2.carbon.governance.api: Could not resolve dependencies for projectorg.wso2.carbon.governance:org.wso2.carbon.governance.api:bundle:4.7.2-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not beresolved: org.wso2.carbon.registry:org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions:jar:4.6.1-SNAPSHOT, org.wso2.carbon.registry:org.wso2.carbon.registry.common:jar:4.6.1-SNAPSHOT, org.wso2.carbon.registry:org.wso2.carbon.registry.admin.api:jar:4.6.1-SNAPSHOT
org.wso2.carbon.registry:org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing:jar:4.6.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.wso2.carbon.registry:org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions:jar:4.6.1-SNAPSHOT in nexuspro-level0 (https://repo.fmr.com/content/groups/level0/)
```

Comment: Are you building the entire repository? If not, please do.

Comment: I'm not building the entire repository. In fact I have reported a bug in WSo2 GREG and Chandana provided a fix lastweek https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance hence trying to build only that. But today when I have visited the Master branch in the above specified URL he has reverted the changes he has done, I don't know why ? Could you please confirm asap.

Comment: Please raise your question in the original question to which Chandana replied.

Answer (score 2):

Please clone below repos, [Move to the relevant tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32509705/3168721) and run an `mvn clean install -e` on each and every repo accordingly.

- https://github.com/wso2/carbon4-kernel.git   tag : 4.4.7
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry.git  tag : 4.6.0
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance.git  tag : 4.7.1
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-governance-extensions.git  tag : 4.5.2
- https://github.com/wso2/jaggery-extensions.git  tag : 1.5.5
- https://github.com/wso2/carbon-store  tag : 2.4.6
- https://github.com/wso2/product-greg.git  tag : 5.3.0

To apply the fix and generate the latest jar you have to apply the fix manually to 5.3.0 tag from your local machine and build the source.