# What i must do that clone github repository, rollback to old version and update submodules on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04, git-checkout, openfl, haxeflixel

I need rebuild openfl/lime for android targeting, under ubuntu 16.04 x64. This allow me use for my haxeflixel project "lime build android" syntax, with android app version 26, which soon will be minimum allowed version, that publish in google playstore.

I need to know the steps for ubuntu 16.04  for clone github project , rollback to old relese and update submodules, like TortoiseGit for windows can do.

this is the github link
https://github.com/openfl/lime
i need clone it and roll back version to 2.9.1, with update submodules.
The newest version of lime on github is 5.9.1.
But i only use sourcetree(windows) etc before, and don't know how solve my problem fast and nice.

OS ubuntu 16.04.3 x64

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a specific tag with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure git is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Create a directory to hold the code and clone the repo:

```
cd ~
mkdir tmp
cd tmp
git clone -b 2.9.1 --recurse-submodules https://github.com/openfl/lime.git openfl_lime
```

This clones the repo into the directory `openfl_lime`, checks it out locally from the tag `2.9.1` and syncs all submodules.

Alternatively, you could just grab the tar or zip file of the release at: https://github.com/openfl/lime/releases/tag/2.9.1

Comment: soon will try it, and how should i do this "and syncs all submodules."? this is final step before i can try to rebuild openfl/lime on linux. @Larry

Comment: The command I showed automatically gets all the submodules and sets them to the correct version for the tag you're checking out (`2.9.1`).  If you don't need the rev tracking, you may be better off just grabbing the release archive and using that.

Comment: ah, see it now... english not my native... i wrong translate structure of sentenсe

Comment: yes, all work (terminal way) ... step by step... and finally i complete rebuild lime with NDK r9d , and now i can build apk with target SDK 26. Look like rabbitcvs and free version of GitKraken can't properly update submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can downgrade lime with haxelib directly:

```
haxelib install lime 2.9.1
```

(you may have to do the same for openfl and other needed libs)

Comment: no , this is not what i try make... i need full rebuild lime with NDK r9d  and hxcpp , that my haxeflixel can "lime build android" apk with target SDK 26.

Comment: Ok =/ Good luck!