# Git: How to checkout to older tag for full Android Codebase

Tags: android, git, repo

I `repo sync` Android Codebase for Android M.

I want to checkout to particular tag for all android projects. I thought `repo forall -c 'git checkout tagName` would work.

Please let me know command to checkout to tag for whole android code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git this should help

Comment: I want to do it for all projects in android source code.This will help if one wants to do it for particular project.