# Verify if a tag was done in the master branch

Tags: git, version-control, repository, dvcs, git-tag

In this project I am working, we do deployments based on tags. Whilst it's obligatory that the tags are done against the master branch (after you merge the release there), sometimes by mistake someone can tag against a dev or release branch, which is incorrect. That causes several problems.

In our deployment script, there is a step in which we do clone a specific tag from git, using a process like the one described in this question: [Download a specific tag with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git)

```
$ git clone
$ git checkout tags/<tag_name>
```

How can I amend this script to check if this tag was actually done against the master branch? I would like to then stop the deployment and throw an error if the branch is not the master.

Thanks.

Comment: Since a tag is just a pointer to a commit, and a branch is also just that, I do not think this is possible. You can check if the tagged commit is reachable from `master`, i.e. is part of it's history. Might that be of help? Does the tag really have to be done on the `master` branch, or is it sufficient if the commit is part of `master`s history?

Comment: I have tested, updated and validated my answer...

Comment: @kowsky I need to understand if the tagged commit is in the master branch, yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As several people noted, your question cannot really be answered until it is reformulated.  This is because a Git tag or branch name simply identifies *one specific commit.*  The desired effect of a branch name is to identify the *tip* commit of a branch, which changes over time, so that the specific commit it identifies also changes over time.  The desired effect of a tag name is to identify one specific commit forever, without changing.  So if someone tags `master`, there will be some moments in time during which parsing the name `master` produces commit hash *H*, and parsing the tag name *also* produces commit hash *H:*

```
if test $(git rev-parse master) = $(git rev-parse $tag^{commit}); then
    echo "master and $tag both identify the same commit"
else
    echo "master and $tag identify two different commits"
fi
```

This particular test is valid until someone makes the branch name `master` advance, after which it is no longer useful.  If we draw this the way I typically like to draw Git commit graphs on StackOverflow, we can see this as:

```
          tag
           |
           v
...--o--o--H   <-- master
          /
 ...--o--o   <-- develop
```

Currently the names `tag` and `master` both identify commit H, which is a merge commit.  As soon as someone creates a *new* commit on `master`, though, the graph becomes:

```
          tag
           |
           v
...--o--o--H--I   <-- master
          /
 ...--o--o   <-- develop
```

Now `master` identifies new commit `I`, so doing the `rev-parse tag^{commit}` will find `H` while doing the `rev-parse master` will find `I` and they won't be equal and the test will fail.

(I drew commit `I` as an ordinary commit here, but it could be a merge commit with a second parent.  If so, imagine a second backwards-pointing line / arrow emerging from `I`, pointing to some other earlier commit.)

[Philippe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49666571/1256452) comes in two forms and answers a slightly different question.  Since branch names *do* move over time, we can use `git branch --contains` to find *all* branch names that make the tagged commit reachable, and see if one of these is `master`.  This will give a true / yes answer for the case above.  Unfortunately, it will also tell you that the tag `error` is contained within `master`—which is true!—for *this* graph:

```
          tag
           |
           v
...--o--o--H   <-- master
          /
 ...--o--G   <-- develop
         ^
         |
       error
```

This is because the tag `error` identifies commit `G`, and commit `G` is *reachable from* commit `H` (by following the second parent of `H`).  In fact any tag along the bottom row, pointing to any commit contained within the `develop` branch, identifies a commit contained within the `master` branch, since *every commit currently on `develop` is also on `master`*.

(Incidentally, the difference between using `git rev-parse your-tag` and using `git rev-list -n 1 your-annotated-tag` is covered by using `git rev-parse $tag^{commit}`.  The issue here is that an annotated tag has an actual repository object, of type "annotated tag", to which the name points; using `git rev-parse your-annotated-tag` alone finds the *tag* object rather than its commit.  The `^{commit}` suffix syntax is described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html).)

There *is* a way to tell whether the commit to which any given tag points is in the history of `master` that occurs only on the first-parent chain.  It is not the prettiest: `git branch --contains` and `git merge-base --is-ancestor` are the usual building blocks for finding reachability but both follow *all* parents.  To follow only *first* parents, we need to use `git rev-list --first-parent` to enumerate all the commits reachable from the name `master` when following only first parents.  Then we simply check whether the tagged revision is in that list.  Here's a bad way to do it that makes clear what we are doing:

```
tagged_commit=$(git rev-parse $tag^{commit}) ||
    fatal "tag $tag does not exist or does not point to a commit object"
found=false
for hash in $(git rev-list --first-parent master); do
    test $hash == $tagged_commit && found=true
done
```

To make this much faster, it would be better to pipe the `git rev-list` output through a `grep` that searches for `$tagged_commit` (with grep's output discarded since we only care about the status):

```
if git rev-list --first-parent master | grep $tagged_commit >/dev/null; then
    echo "$tag points to a commit reachable via first-parent from master"
else
    echo "$tag does not point to a commit reachable via first-parent from master"
fi
```

for instance.  (One flaw here is that `git rev-list` will run all the way through every reachable commit; in a large repository, this can take *seconds*.)

Answer (score 8):

In the case of a lightweight tag:

```
git branch --contains $(git rev-parse your-tag) | grep '^* master$'
```

In the case of an annotated tag:

```
git branch --contains $(git rev-list -n 1 your-annotated-tag) | grep '^* master$'
```

The result should not be empty if the commit pointed by the tag is in `master`. (You could even test the exit code of the `grep`, which returns `0` if in `master` and `1` if not.)

Comment: FYI this fails if the string `master` is in the branch name - im using this:
`git branch --contains $(git rev-parse your-tag) | grep '^master$'`

Comment: Indeed ;) It's seems strange to use `master` but you're right. I've updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: idk if the currently accepted answer was accepted before the OP's final edits, but this answer should be the accepted answer based on intent.

Comment: Actually `grep '^master$'` fails to find the `master` branch there is a space before master so it should be `git branch --contains $(git rev-parse your-tag) | grep ' master$'`

Answer (score 5):

git branch -a --contains  | grep master | cut -d/ -f3

example:

```bash
git branch -a --contains v.1.2.3 | grep master | cut -d/ -f3
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't. At least not after the fact.

What you could do is to create an *annotated tag*. This puts a message on the tag.
This message could then contain the branch name of the currently checked out branch. You can then check that this message contains `master`.

Another solution is to use a `pre-push` commit hook that checks that any new tags to be pushed is reachable from the `master` branch.

Both solutions require setup on the client side and thus can be sidestepped or disabled by silly or malicious users.

If you have control of your Git repository manager, you could look into having a pre-receive hook testing for the same reachability criteria.

My advice would be to figure out the proper way to automate your release-tagging procedure.

Good luck!