# Can I git pull a project I have several commits before?

Tags: git

Having project at bitbucket how can I git pull a project with state before last 2 commits and 1 merge?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean "How to *clone* a project at some arbitrary point in the past"?

Comment: Are you trying to just checkout the files in your sandbox to examine them? Then `git checkout <commit>` will do. Or are you trying to reset your local branch to the state you're describing? Or are you trying to update the remote to state you're describing?

Comment: By the way, `git pull` is simply `git fetch` followed by `git merge` (by default) or `git rebase` (if you changed your configuration). I recommend avoiding `git pull` and using `git fetch` instead: that way, you can avoid creating unintended merges. After fetching, look and the commit graph, and either merge or rebase if necessary and if you know that's what you want to do.

Comment: @Romain Valeri, yes

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791959/download-a-specific-tag-with-git) help?